# Adding a splash screen to Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, flutter-widget

How would you approach adding a splash screen to Flutter apps? It should load and display before any other content. Currently, there is a brief flash of color before the Scaffold(home:X) widget loads.

Comment: I dont know if its the right way to add a splash screen by setting a custom timer,I dont like keeping processors idle why not do some house keeping tasks like checking the required files or directories or sync some logs,or backup some files in the background and do the branding on the front in the mean time.after all 3-4 secs is a lot of time for a processor.

Comment: This link explains how to do it: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen

Comment: See also [Splash screens for dark and light mode in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/splash-screens-for-dark-and-light-mode-in-flutter-eb85f1aa025)

Comment: I created a tutorial for Flutter Splash Screen without using any libraries and one with libraries i.e. Flutter Native Splash, they will definitely help you.

Without any Library:  https://youtu.be/MCosWsD5yKc
With Flutter Native Splash: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV19Hawgpeg

Answer (score 391, accepted):

I want to shed some more light on the actual way of doing a Splash screen in Flutter.

I followed a little bit the trace [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8147) and I saw that things aren't looking so bad about the Splash Screen in Flutter.

Maybe most of the devs (like me) are thinking that there isn't a Splash screen by default in Flutter and they need to do something about that. There is a Splash screen, but it's with white background and nobody can understand that there is already a splash screen for iOS and Android by default.

The only thing that the developer needs to do is to put the Branding image in the right place and the splash screen will start working just like that.

Here is how you can do it step by step:

**First on Android** (because is my favorite Platform :) )

1. Find the "android" folder in your Flutter project.
2. Browse to the app -> src -> main -> res folder and place all of the variants of your branding image in the corresponding folders. For example:

- the image with density 1 needs to be placed in mipmap-mdpi,
- the image with density 1.5 needs to be placed in mipmap-hdpi,
- the image with density 2 needs to be placed in mipmap-xhdpi,
- the image with density 3 needs to be placed in mipmap-xxhdpi,
- the image with density 4 needs to be placed in mipmap-xxxhdpi,

By default in the android folder there isn't a drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc., but we can create them if we want. Because of that fact the images need to be placed in the mipmap folders. Also the default XML code about the Splash screen (in Android) is going to use @mipmap, instead of @drawable resource (you can change it if you want).

3. The last step on Android is to uncomment some of the XML code in drawable/launch_background.xml file. Browse to app -> src -> main -> res-> drawable and open launch_background.xml. Inside this file, you shall see why the Slash screen background is white. To apply the branding image which we placed in step 2, we have to uncomment some of the XML code in your launch_background.xml file. After the change, the code should look like:

   ```
    <!--<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />-->

    <item>

        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/your_image_name" />

    </item>
   ```

Please pay attention that we comment the XML code for the white background and uncomment the code about the mipmap image. If somebody is interested the file launch_background.xml is used in styles.xml file.

**Second on iOS:**

1. Find the "ios" folder in your Flutter project.
2. Browse to Runner -> Assets.xcassets -> LaunchImage.imageset. There should be LaunchImage.png, LaunchImage@2x.png, etc. Now you have to replace these images with your branding image variants. For example:

- the image with density 1 needs to override LaunchImage.png,
- the image with density 2 needs to override LaunchImage@2x.png,
- the image with density 3 needs to override LaunchImage@3x.png,
- the image with density 4 needs to override LaunchImage@4x.png,

If I am not wrong LaunchImage@4x.png doesn't exist by default, but you can easily create one. If LaunchImage@4x.png doesn't exist, you have to declare it in the Contents.json file as well, which is in the same directory as the images. After the change my Contents.json file looks like this :

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage@4x.png",
      "scale" : "4x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

That should be all you need, next time when you run your app, on Android or iOS you should have the right Splash Screen with the branding image which you added.

Thanks

Comment: I got error `Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'` in Android Studio 3.1.1 (even after cache rebuild), however, the app compiled and ran without error, and launcher graphic displayed.

Comment: i have the same issue, however, i can't run it as at runtime it crashes and tells me the image is missing. but it can't resolve mipmap for some reason. Anyone an idea why this is?

Comment: Hi guys, not sure why you have this issue, but for me looks like project sync problem (there isn't any other reason to not find the resource if it is there). I don't know how to resolve it because I never had this issue, but try to sync the project, clean, rebuild etc. what ever it is possible in you IDEA. Also try to use the resource in drawable folder and replace mipmap annotation with drawable annotation. I am just guessing now :)

Comment: Curious as to why you are adding the 4x image. XCode seems to expect only 3x, is there a reason you add the 4x?

Comment: @sbilstein you are right xCode doesn't assign 4x to the asset, I have tried it without 4x and it wasn't working for me, but after adding 4x it worked.

Comment: Great answer!! In case that you need more detail, I created a tutorial about this : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-splash-screen-9f4e05542548

Comment: @Sniper how would one add animation in this case?

Comment: Thanks for asking @RoyalGriffin. First of all to have animation on your Splash is not recommend by Apple and Google, but this of course can't stop you from doing it :). If you want to have animation you shall need to follow some custom approach, perhaps create new landing screen and add some animation there and then when the animation finishes, proceed to the app home screen. The way of having Splash screen described here is a standard way and unlocks only Splash screen as static image resource.

Comment: But I need more e.g. when during splash then creating/importing local db then only splash ends. How to do this?

Comment: @Sniper a question about this method: I have also implemented this approach to the splash screen for Android and iOS, rather than creating a dedicated stateless/full for that, but then I noticed I have no control over the splash....meaning that, with this approach, how do i, for example, hold the splash screen while I am loading something or doing anything needed in the background before the app starts??

Comment: @codeKiller pls have a look RoyalGriffin's question above and my answer to it. Basically if you want to wait until something loads in the background and then display your first screen, you need to block the user interface with some view/screen and then proceed in the first screen when the app is ready. The approach in my post is the most simple way to display static image as splash, but this is just your application's windowBackground, it is not even a screen.

Comment: I just want to change the color from white to something else. is this possible? I tried your approach but still showing white on initial load

Comment: @IanB I had the same error I just restarted the ide and its working even though the ide prompts for that resolve error with red but it works without any errors

Comment: Also the splashscreen appears to be too fast is there any way to slow it may be some kind of delay in xml is it possible?

Comment: Official [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-splash-screen) has this covered.

Comment: I had everything right, except for having the images in the mipmap folder. Moving the images to the mipmap folder stopped the splash screen from stretching.

Comment: I was wrong, moving the images to the mipmap folder still makes them stretched on some devices.

Comment: After following this steps. status bar is hidden in my next screens also. Can you help me with this? @Stoycho Andreev

Comment: Is there a way to add text with icon on the screen on android with this method?

Comment: With this method , perhaps the only way is to merge that text and icon into image and display that image instead

Comment: Why does the image come out so tiny though? How do you make a larger splash image?

Comment: I didi and it works fine. BUT when a user press back, it goes to this screen instead of terminating the app.

Comment: works fine, but takes too long to start. And when the app is the background, when i bring it back to fore screen in stacks on the launcher page

Comment: @MichaelTolsma I am also facing same issue. Did you fix it? If so how?

Comment: @KirenSiva I don't remember, but I think I just tried using different sized image files.

Comment: @MichaelTolsma Thank you for your reply. I fixed it by giving 1000X1000 px image

Comment: For those who got the error Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/icon.png' try to give the name of the file without the extenstion, like '@mipmap/icon'. Also @b.john did you fix the issue with the timing and it showing up when you minimise the app.

Comment: its ok now. fixed

Comment: Hey, is there any way to change the splash screen color depending on the app theme? (Not system default theme, but the one chosen by user)

Comment: SUPER! This works... but is there any ways to show a small animation rather than just the LOGO??

Comment: @StoychoAndreev it's very very very Good. You show put in medium! it's more clear than all tutorials available!

Comment: How about adding BL(checking whether user is already logged in) in Splash Screen? Can't we add some code in splash screen?

Comment: How can we test this Splashscreen? Like, how to slow down the loading process to check if there is actually one?

Comment: Just to add to this. If your android app min version is set to 21 and above, you should make the changes in the drawable-v21 folder instead.

Comment: @IanB make sure  you have ic_launcher image in your mipmap folder

Comment: @StoychoAndreev, I've added an icon to my Flutter 3.19.3 app, and I didn't have to do anything but that also changed the splash screen, displaying my custom icon at the center. Is this now default behavior in flutter 3.19? I've tested this default splash screen to work on both Android 13 device and 14 emulator. Will this work on previous versions as well?

Answer (score 72):

The easiest way to add a splash screen in flutter is imho this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

[image]

## Installation guide (by the author of the package):

### 1. Setting the splash screen

Add your settings to your project's pubspec.yaml file or create a file in your root project folder named flutter_native_splash.yaml with your settings.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "42a5f5"
```

image must be a png file.

You can use # in color as well. color: "#42a5f5"
You can also set android or ios to false if you don't want to create a splash screen for a specific platform.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "42a5f5"
  android: false
```

In case your image should use all available screen (width and height) you can use fill property.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "42a5f5"
  fill: true
```

Note: fill property is not yet implemented for iOS splash screens.

If you want to disable full screen splash screen on Android you can use android_disable_fullscreen property.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "42a5f5"
  android_disable_fullscreen: true
```

### 2. Run the package

After adding your settings, run the package with

`flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`
When the package finishes running your splash screen is ready.

Comment: if iOS splash wasn't filling the screen add `ios_content_mode:scaleToFill` in `pubspec.yaml` file and re-run `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`

Comment: I used this package, works perfect, and no fiddling around with files. Best answer.

Answer (score 42):

Flutter actually gives a simpler way to add Splash Screen to our application.
We first need to design a basic page as we design other app screens. You need to make it a *StatefulWidget* since the state of this will change in a few seconds.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen())));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/splash.png'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Logic**
Inside the *initState()*, call a *Timer()* with the duration, as you wish, I made it 3 seconds, once done push the navigator to Home Screen of our application.

**Note:** The application should show the splash screen only once, the user should not go back to it again on back button press. For this, we use ***Navigator.pushReplacement()***, It will move to a new screen and remove the previous screen from the navigation history stack.

For a better understanding, visit [Flutter: Design your own Splash Screen](https://medium.com/kick-start-fluttering/flutter-design-your-own-splashscreen-d0612b17db23)

Comment: The default white splash screen will still show for 1+ seconds before this custom one is shown. Have to override in the generated xcode and android projects to eliminate it.

Comment: Yes. Default spalsh screen in iOS and android will always appear, this flutter splash screen is addition to that.

Comment: The thing is this example is not reliable.... What if your app loads for more than 3s due to reasons such as the network connectivity?

Comment: For additional customization, I support this answer more. I want to first perform an HTTP request while displaying a splash screen. This approach was much more easier

Comment: I prefer it this way. Does it have to be a StatefulWidget though? I think I made it work with a StatelessWidget.

Answer (score 18):

There isn't a good example of this yet, but you can do it yourself using the native tools for each platform:

iOS: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/creating-launch-screens-ios

Android: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Subscribe to [issue 8147](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8147) for updates on example code for splash screens. If the black flicker between the splash screen and the app on iOS bothers you, subscribe to [issue 8127](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8127) for updates.

*Edit: As of August 31, 2017, improved support for splash screens is now available in the new project template. See [#11505](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/11505).*

Comment: Is there an example how to actually add a splashscreen. When I start the new template I dont see a splashscreen

Comment: @RideSun please see my answer

Comment: How can I make the splash-screen last longer? should I change some code in the activity?

Comment: But I need more e.g. when during splash then creating/importing local db then only splash ends

Answer (score 16):

For Android, go to **android > app > src > main > res > drawable > launcher_background.xml**

Now uncomment this and replace **@mipmap/launch_image**, with your image location.

```
<item>
      <bitmap
          android:gravity="center"
          android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
</item>
```

You can change the colour of your screen here -

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: this worked for me...   but the iOS part... not playing so good

Comment: check this out - https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#updating-the-launch-screen

Comment: I figured it out...   apparently the iOS image was bad.   iOS and ANDROID both work perfect now.  false alarm

Comment: @SmrutiRanjanRana what is the ideal size for this image?

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if there were an example of the image location. Otherwise the user has to guess how to add the path.

Comment: is there a way to add custom timer for the splashscreen

Answer (score 14):

persons who are getting the error like image not found after applying the verified answer make sure that you are adding **@mipmap/ic_launcher** instead of **@mipmap/ ic_launcher.png**

Comment: Your IDE would tell you this once you hover your cursor on the error

Answer (score 11):

This is the error free and best way to add dynamic splash screen in Flutter.

**MAIN.DART**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constant.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'GridView Demo',
      home: SplashScreen(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        accentColor: Color(0xFF761322),
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        SPLASH_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
        HOME_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => BasicTable(),
        //GRID_ITEM_DETAILS_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => GridItemDetails(),
      },
    ));
```

**SPLASHSCREEN.DART**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_example/constants.dart';


class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SplashScreenState createState() => new SplashScreenState();
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _visible = true;

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;

  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 3);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HOME_SCREEN);
  }

@override
dispose() {
  animationController.dispose();  
  super.dispose();
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    animation =
        new CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);

    animation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
    animationController.forward();

    setState(() {
      _visible = !_visible;
    });
    startTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                child: new Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/powered_by.png',
                  height: 25.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Image.asset(
                'assets/images/logo.png',
                width: animation.value * 250,
                height: animation.value * 250,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CONSTANTS.DART**

```
String SPLASH_SCREEN='SPLASH_SCREEN';
String HOME_SCREEN='HOME_SCREEN';
```

**HOMESCREEN.DART**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BasicTable extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Table Widget")),
      body: Center(child: Text("Table Widget")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a best way.

Comment: That's not a splash screen. A splash screen is shown by ios or android before your app starts. Therefore you cannot do it in the app (since the app isn't started yet...). Incorrect answer.

Answer (score 8):

Both @Collin Jackson and @Sniper are right. You can follow these steps to set up launch images in android and iOS respectively. Then in your MyApp(), in your initState(), you can use Future.delayed to set up a timer or call any api. Until the response is returned from the Future, your launch icons will be shown and then as the response come, you can move to the screen you want to go to after the splash screen. You can see this link : [Flutter Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669025/flutter-splash-screen)

Comment: Please , when linking to another page out of SO, post the answering part of the content here to avoid dead links.

Answer (score 7):

You should try below code, worked for me

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:attendance/components/appbar.dart';
import 'package:attendance/homepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {


void handleTimeout() {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => new MyHomePage()));
}

startTimeout() async {
  var duration = const Duration(seconds: 3);
  return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout);
}

@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();

  _iconAnimationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 2000));

  _iconAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _iconAnimationController, curve: Curves.easeIn);
  _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));

  _iconAnimationController.forward();

  startTimeout();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Image(
        image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
        width: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
        height: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
      )),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: can you please post the complete code (a code we can run independently without the need to define our variables) or a github link?

Comment: Not a splash screen either. This is missing the point.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple ways you could do this, but the easiest one which I use is:

For Launch Icons I use the flutter library [Flutter Launcher Icon](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

**For the Custom Splash Screen** I create different Screen resolutions and then add the splash images in the mipmap folder as per the resolution for Android.

The last part is adjusting the launch_background.xml in the drawable folder in res folder in Android.

Just change your code to look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/<splashfilename>" />     --> -->

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/<Your splash image name here as per the mipmap folder>"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Few devs I have seen add the splash as drawable, I tried this but somehow the build fails in Flutter 1.0.0 and Dart SDK 2.0+. Therefore I prefer to add the splash in bitmap section.

iOS Splash-screen creation is rather simpler.

In the Runner folder in iOS just update the LaunchImage.png files with your custom Splash screen images with same names as LaunchImage.png @2x, @3x, @4x.

Just an addition I feel its good to have a 4x image as well in the LaunchImage.imageset. Just update your code in Content.json with following lines, below 3x scale to add a 4x scale option:

```
{
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage@4x.png",
      "scale" : "4x"
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps for configuring the splash screen in both IOS and Android platforms for your Flutter app.

**IOS Platform**

All apps submitted to the Apple App Store must use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen. Let’s do this in 3 steps:-

*Step 1*: Open ios/Runner.xcworkspace from the root of your app directory.

*Step 2*: Select Runner/Assets.xcassets from the Project Navigator and drag your launch images of all sizes (2x, 3x, etc.). You can also generate different sizes of images from https://appicon.co/#image-sets

[image]

*Step 3*: You can see the LaunchScreen.storyboard file is showing the provided image, here you can also change the position of the image by simply dragging the image. For more information please see official documentation https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/

[image]

**Android Platform**

In Android, a launch screen is shown while your Android app initializes. Let’s set this launch screen in 3 steps:-

*Step 1*: Open android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml file.

*Step 2*: At line number 4 you can select the desired colour:-

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

*Step 3*: At line number 10 you can change the image:-

```
android:src="@mipmap/launch_image"
```

[image]

That's all, you are done! Happy Coding :)

Comment: i test this solution and worked !  thanks  .

Answer (score 4):

Adding a page like below and routing might help

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutkart/utils/flutkart.dart';
import 'package:flutkart/utils/my_navigator.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => MyNavigator.goToIntro(context));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.redAccent),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        radius: 50.0,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.greenAccent,
                          size: 50.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        Flutkart.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      Flutkart.store,
                      softWrap: true,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to follow through, see: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNBuo-7zg2Q

Comment: Not a splash screen. There's at least 5, 6 answers on this page that show an in-app "first screen" but first screen shows after the actual splash screen, and the question is about the splash (or loading) screen iOS and Android show.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want a secondary splash screen (after the native one), here is a simple example that works:

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  SplashPage(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      // Navigate here to next screen
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Splash screen here');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Flutter provides you the ability to have a splash screen by default but there are a lot of plugins that can do the job. If you don't want to use a plugin for the task and you're worried that adding a new plugin might affect your app size. Then you can do it like this.

**FOR Android**

Open launch_background.xml then you can put in the splash screen image, or gradient color you want. This is the first thing your user sees when they open your app.
[image]

**For IOS**

Open your app using Xcode, Click on Runner > Assest.xcassets > LaunchImage, You can add the image here. If you want to edit what position launch screen image should take or look like you can edit it on LaunchScreen.storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

make your material App like this

=> Add dependency

=> import import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:tic_tac_toe/HomePage.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new MyApp(),
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 6,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new HomePage(),
      title: new Text('Welcome',
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 26.0,
        color: Colors.purple,
       ),
      ),
      image: Image.asset("images/pic9.png"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      photoSize: 150.0,
    );
  }
}
```

The final screen output like this you can change second according to your requirements
the circle will be round circular

[image]

Comment: Add dependencies=>                dynamic_theme: ^1.0.1

Comment: There is no import for SplashScreen

Comment: yes exactly right, there are a number of ways to do that, but in the answer, I will tell you how you can add splash screen with the help of this package https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_theme

Comment: But you forgot to write which dependency has to be in pubspec.yaml

Comment: please read the first comment  Add dependencies=> dynamic_theme: ^1.0.1

Answer (score 4):

The Simplest way to do that is by using [flutter_native_splash package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

First of all, add it to your dev dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.3.1 # make sure to us the latest version
```

Now, you can configure your splash screen as you like:

```yaml
     flutter_native_splash:

      android: true # show for android, you may set it to false
      ios: true # show for IOS, you may set it to false

      image: assets\logo.png # the default image for light and dark themes. Until now, images should be png images
      image_dark: aassets\logo_dark.png # It will override the 'image' in the dark mode

      color: "#ffffff" # the default color for light and dark themes
      color_dark: "#0a0a0a" # will override the 'color' in the dark mode

      android_gravity: fill # make the image fill the screen for android
      ios_content_mode: scaleAspectFill # make the image fill the screen for android
```

After doing so, run:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

You will notice that ".\android\app\src\main\res*" have changed and the new splash screen was added.

Answer (score 3):

The code from Jaldhi Bhatt doesn't works for me.

Flutter throws a '[Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator/51905078#51905078).'

I fixed the code wrapping the Navigator consumer component inside of another component that initialize the Navigator context using routes, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator/51905078#51905078) article.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my-app/view/main-view.dart';

class SplashView extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
          builder: (context) => new _SplashContent(),
        ),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/main': (BuildContext context) => new MainView()}
    );
  }
}

class _SplashContent extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _SplashContentState createState() => new _SplashContentState();
}

class _SplashContentState extends State<_SplashContent>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  var _iconAnimationController;
  var _iconAnimation;

  startTimeout() async {
    var duration = const Duration(seconds: 3);
    return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout);
  }

  void handleTimeout() {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/main");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _iconAnimationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 2000));

    _iconAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _iconAnimationController, curve: Curves.easeIn);
    _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));

    _iconAnimationController.forward();

    startTimeout();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: new Image(
          image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
          width: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
          height: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as well? A plain code block alone isn't all that informative

Answer (score 2):

**For Android**
 app -> src -> main -> res ->drawble->launch_background.xml
and uncomment 
the commented block like this

```
<item>
  <bitmap
      android:gravity="center"
      android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" /></item>
```

is there any one face any error after coding like this
Use sync with system in android studio or invalidate cache and reset.This solved my problem
In flutter debug mode take some time take for splash screen .After build it will reduce like native android

Comment: this answer before v2 and null-safty version .  please update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Android, go to this path,

android > app > src > main > res > drawable > launcher_background.xml

default code is for white colour background screen.
like this,

```
<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
 <item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
</item>
```

[image]
You can changes its color or modify this by adding icon or any custom design. for more customisation detail checkout this for android.

---

for Ios

open Ios project in Xcode.

select Runner and then.inside Runner folder Main.Storyboard file is there,
enter image description here

by default its colour is white, you can customise or change colour this by your requirement, for more customisation check out this Ios.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is match the flutter default splash color with your custom flutter (widget class) splash. As you cannot override the default native splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!-- <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> -->
 
 <item android:drawable="@color/custom_color" /> <!-- // Modified \\ -->
 
 <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
  <!-- <item>
      <bitmap
          android:gravity="center"
          android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
  </item> -->
 </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter.dev already gives the best answer for it, that is not a bug neither a problem, just config.
Just take time read and everything will be solved. Have a nice day everyone.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relevant anymore, as the same answer was already given on April 9th.

Comment: But mine is way more straight to the point to the best font.

Comment: thanks. your refer is good and cover ios&android device.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it two ways

1. Go to the native package and an initial page. like in Native Android package create a drawable
2. Create a dart screen to display for some time

I found a complete explanation for [remove white screen](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app.html) and display [splash screen here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/05/flutter-application-branding-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

when we have to get user location or other data before app start we can use custom splash screen in flutter and it will make your app user friendly

Here is code Example:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bmi/HomePage.dart';
import 'dart:async';

main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreen();
 }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>{
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    when we have to get data we can show splash 
    Like this:- 
    FutureMethodForData.then((value) {
       Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          )
        );

    });
    Or we can show splash for fix duration like this:-
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(
        seconds: 4
      ),
      (){
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          )
        );
      }
  );
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: // add image text or whatever you want as splash
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people following the steps to the letter like I was and still not getting it to work...

Pay attention if you have a **drawable-v21** folder as you need to copy your code from drawable  folder > launch_background.xml code into the drawable-v21 folder > launch_background.xml

And my project didn't like android:src="@**mipmap**/launch" />

Therefore I have android:src="@**drawable**/launch" />

Answer (score -1):

```
SplashScreen(
          seconds: 3,
          navigateAfterSeconds: new MyApp(),
          // title: new Text(
          //   'Welcome In SplashScreen',
          //   style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
          // ),
          image: new Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Tesla_Motors.svg/1200px-Tesla_Motors.svg.png'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle(),
          photoSize: 150.0,
          loaderColor: Colors.black),
    ),
  );
```