# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to start a new screen within an onTap but I get the following error:

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a
>   Navigator.

The code I am using to navigate is:

```
onTap: () { Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/settings'); },
```

I have set up a route in my app as follows:

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/settings': (BuildContext context) => new SettingsPage(),
},
```

I've tried to copy the code using the stocks sample application. I've looked at the Navigator and Route documentation and can't figure out how the context can be made to include a Navigator. The `context` being used in the onTap is referenced from the parameter passed into the build method:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

SettingsPage is a class as follows:

```
class SettingsPage extends Navigator {

Widget buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
  return new AppBar(
    title: const Text('Settings')
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: buildAppBar(context),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: this error comes by inserting in your widget tree a MaterialApp or WidgetApp widget. Try adding MaterialApp widget in main method and remaining code in stateless or stateful widget then issue will be resolved.

Comment: One of the best ways to handle this is described by this answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73433546/5365164

Answer (score 371, accepted):

*TLDR*: Wrap the widget which needs to access to `Navigator` into a `Builder` or extract that sub-tree into a class. And use the new `BuildContext` to access `Navigator`.

---

This error is unrelated to the destination. It happens because you used a `context` that doesn't contain a `Navigator` instance as parent.

**How do I create a Navigator instance then ?**

This is usually done by inserting in your widget tree a `MaterialApp` or `WidgetsApp`. Although you can do it manually by using `Navigator` directly but less recommended. Then, all children of such widget can access `NavigatorState` using `Navigator.of(context)`.

**Wait, I already have a `MaterialApp`/`WidgetsApp`!**

That's most likely the case. But this error can still happen when you use a `context` that is a parent of `MaterialApp`/`WidgetsApp`.

This happens because when you do `Navigator.of(context)`, it will start from the widget associated to the `context` used, and then go upward in the widget tree until it either finds a `Navigator` or there's no more widgets to iterate through.

In the first case, everything is fine. In the second, it throws

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

**So, how do I fix it ?**

First, let's reproduce this error:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Foo"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This example creates a button that attempts to go to '/' on click but will instead throw an exception.

Notice here that in the

```dart
onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/"),
```

we used `context` passed by `build` of `MyApp`.

The problem is, `MyApp` is actually a parent of `MaterialApp`, as it's the widget who instantiates `MaterialApp`! Therefore, `MyApp`'s `BuildContext` doesn't have a `MaterialApp` as parent.

To solve this problem, we need to use a different `context`.

In this situation, the easiest solution is to introduce a new widget as child of `MaterialApp`, and then use that widget's context to do the `Navigator` call.

There are a few ways to achieve this. You can extract `home` into a custom class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome()
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Foo"),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can use `Builder`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Foo"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez This answer assumes that you want to use a single widget for home.  But this solution does not extend to cases where you use a router, and therefore need to implement some kind of base widget for every route that you have.  For example, if you needed to initialize a listener in a common widget that needed to use the Navigator, this wouldn't work because there is no common widget to all routes.  The widget gets duplicated, and so does your listener.

Answer (score 66):

I had the same problem. The solution I´ve found is very simple:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
   MaterialApp(
    home: YourApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This was the easiest solution. To the point!

Comment: Shouldn't we only be using the `MatrialApp` widget one time in the widget tree?

Answer (score 42):

Make sure your current parent widget not with same level with MaterialApp

**Wrong Way**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //wrong way: use context in same level tree with MaterialApp
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScanScreen()));
              },
              child: const Text('SCAN')),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Right way**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ));

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
            //right way: use context in below level tree with MaterialApp
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScanScreen()));
            },
            child: const Text('SCAN')),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Best explanation

Comment: how to pass multiple parameters and get/use them on another screen? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh simply pass it by constructor of your widget (Class)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you please update your answer by adding different types of 2 params? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh sorry for late replay, To keep the clear answer directly to main the question above i cant edit it.

If you still need help, I can contact you :)

Answer (score 22):

Just like with a Scaffold you can use a `GlobalKey`. It doesn't need context.

```
final _navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void _navigateToLogin() {
  _navKey.currentState.popUntil((r) => r.isFirst);
  _navKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed(LoginRoute.name);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: _navKey,
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. if you want to push new route from MyApp outside the MaterialApp then this is the way..

Comment: I got a bug doing this: `If no route is provided using home, routes, onGenerateRoute, or onUnknownRoute, a non-null callback for the builder property must be provided, and the other navigator-related properties, navigatorKey, initialRoute, and navigatorObservers, must have their initial values (null, null, and the empty list, respectively).`

Comment: how to pass multiple parameters and get/use them on another screen? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I set up this simple example for routing in a flutter app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/settings': (BuildContext context) => new SettingsPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('TestProject'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new FlatButton(
          child: const Text('Go to Settings'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/settings')
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('SettingsPage'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Text('Settings')
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Note, that the SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget and not Navigator.  I'm not able to reproduce your error.

Does this example help you in building your app? Let me know if I can help you with anything else.

Comment: Yes this helped! I had set `home: new Scaffold(appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('GroupUp'),),` in the constructor of the MaterialApp rather than creating another Widget. (At least I think that was the issue)

Comment: Where did you have your onTap than?

Comment: Maybe you're running into https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15919

Comment: how to pass multiple parameters and get/use them on another screen? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You should rewrite your code in main.dart 
FROM:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

TO

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'Your title',
  home: MyApp(),));}
```

The point is to have the home property to be your first page
this worked for me, I hope it will help someone in the future

Answer (score 5):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15919#issuecomment-383810916) If your navigator is inside Material context navigator push will give this error. if you create a new widget and assign it to the material app home navigator will work.

**This won't work**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Title"),
        ),
        body: new Center(child: new Text("Click Me")),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          onPressed: () {
            print("Clicked");
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new AddTaskScreen()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This will work**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: new Center(child: new Text("Click Me")),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        onPressed: () {
          print("Clicked");
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new AddTaskScreen()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to pass multiple parameters and get/use them on another screen? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A complete and tested solution:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my-app/view/main-view.dart';

class SplashView extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
          builder: (context) => new _SplashContent(),
        ),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/main': (BuildContext context) => new MainView()}
    );
  }
}

class _SplashContent extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _SplashContentState createState() => new _SplashContentState();
}

class _SplashContentState extends State<_SplashContent>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  var _iconAnimationController;
  var _iconAnimation;

  startTimeout() async {
    var duration = const Duration(seconds: 3);
    return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout);
  }

  void handleTimeout() {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/main");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _iconAnimationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 2000));

    _iconAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _iconAnimationController, curve: Curves.easeIn);
    _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));

    _iconAnimationController.forward();

    startTimeout();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: new Image(
          image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
          width: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
          height: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how to pass multiple parameters and get/use them on another screen? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### It is Simple

instead using this normal code

```
`runApp(BasicBankingSystem());`
```

---

#### wrap it with MaterialApp

```
runApp(MaterialApp(home: BasicBankingSystem()));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and solved by removing **home** from **MaterialApp** and use **initialRoute** instead.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyApp(),
        '/settings': (context) => SettingsPage(),
      },
    );
```

And

```dart
onTap: () => {
               Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/settings")
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the context on the widget that tries to navigate is still using the material widget.

The short answer for the solution is to :

> extract your widget

that has navigation to new class so it has a different context when calling the navigation

Answer (score 1):

```
Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return TextButton(
              child: const Text('Bearbeiten'),
              onPressed:(){
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const gotothesiteyouwant()),
                );                        
              });
          }
        ),
```

This builder Widget helped me a Lot

Answer (score 0):

When your screen is not navigated from other screen,you don't initially have access to the navigator,Because it is not instantiated yet.So in that case wrap your widget with builder and extract context from there.This worked for me.

```
builder: (context) => Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Foo"),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/"),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca use this plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/get/versions/2.0.2

in The MaterialApp assign property navigatorKey: Get.key,

```
MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: Get.key,
      initialRoute: "/",
     );
```

you can access `Get.toNamed("Your route name");`

Answer (score 0):

Change your main function example:

```
void main() {
    runApp(
        MaterialApp(
            title: 'Your title',
            home: MyApp(),
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()),);
}
```

instead of this

```
void main() {runApp(MyApp());}
```

Wrap with materialapp

**reproduce code**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // reproduce code
  runApp(MyApp());
  // working switch //
  // runApp(
  //
  //   MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()),);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body:
                Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => IntroPage(Isscar4: true)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'CAR',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: '4',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => IntroPage(Isscar4: false)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'BIKE',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 3,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: '2',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ])));
  }

  MaterialApp Swithwidget(istrue) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: IntroPage(
          Isscar4: istrue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Hi extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("df"),
    );
  }
}

class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Isscar4;

  IntroPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.Isscar4,
  }) : super(key: key);

  List<Widget> listPagesViewModel = [];

  List<IntroModel> models = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> intro = fetchIntroApi(Isscar4);

    intro.forEach((element) {
      var element2 = element as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var cd = IntroModel.fromJson(element2);
      models.add(cd);
    });
    models.forEach((element) {
      listPagesViewModel.add(Text(""));
    });

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(),
        ));
  }

  List fetchIntroApi(bool bool) {
    var four = bool;
    if (four) {
      var data =
          '[ {"name_Title": "title name1","description": "description1"}, {"name_Title": "title name2","description": "description2"}, {"name_Title": "title name3","description": "description3"}, {"name_Title": "title name4","description": "description4"} ]';
      return json.decode(data);
    } else {
      var data =
          '[ {"name_Title": "title name","description": "description1"}, {"name_Title": "title name2","description": "description2"}, {"name_Title": "title name3","description": "description3"} ]';

      return json.decode(data);
    }
  }
}

class IntroModel {
  String? nameTitle;
  String? description;

  IntroModel({this.nameTitle, this.description});

  IntroModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    nameTitle = json['name_Title'];
    description = json['description'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name_Title'] = this.nameTitle;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return TextButton(
                  child: const Text('Bearbeiten'),
                  onPressed:(){
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const gotothesiteyouwant()),
                    );                        
                  });
              }
            ),
```

Comment: sorry for bad formating .... but this worked fine for me ... thanks @lava

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Splash Screen',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          ),
          home: MyState(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
      }
    
    void main() {
      runApp(Splash());
    }

    class MyState extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyState> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 3),
                ()=>Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                    (context) =>
                    Login()
                )
            )
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child:  Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:   MainAxisAlignment.center ,
            children: [
              Container(
                child:
                Image.asset("assets/images/herosplash.png"),
          
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here, all you need is to make MaterialApp the parent of your Build. This is because the context that you've used to navigate to a different screen is finding a MaterialApp or a WidgetApp as a parent of the build.

And Since in your case, the situation is the opposite, therefore you need to modify it by either calling a new Stateless widget the parent of is the MaterialApp or by simply using a Builder as `home: Builder` in `MaterialApp`.

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the Button Widget inside a Builder Widget fixed my issue. Below is the code snippet for the same.

```
                        Builder(
                        builder: (context) => ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignIn(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text('Sign in'),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happen when you want to route page from `main.dart` and you should cut your code from `main.dart` and transfer to another page (second page) so after that you have to route which page in second page  and call it in the main.dart