# WHY "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator"

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

I know how to solve the problem but I don't why it's happening:

I've an app with 2 screens:

This main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'HomeActivity.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new HomeActivity();
  }
}
```

HomeActivity.Dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'AddGameActivity.dart';

class HomeActivity extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: new Text("Home")),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new AddGameActivity())),
            child: new Icon(Icons.add))),
    );
  }
```

So here I've a screen with a FAB button to navigate me to `AddGameActivity`, when I press the FAB button this is the error message:

> navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Now to solve this I added `MaterialApp` to `main.dart` and removed it from `HomeActivity.dart` like this:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'HomeActivity.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(home: HomeActivity());
    }
}
```

HomeActivity:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'AddGameActivity.dart';

class HomeActivity extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: new Text("Home")),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new AddGameActivity())),
            child: new Icon(Icons.add)));
  }
}
```

In that case when I add the Material app in `main.dart` it works correctly without any problem.

So my questions is WHY is this happening? in both of the ways I've a `Material app` which has a `Scaffold` inside !

Comment: Check this excellent answer from Reimi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51292613/666221

Comment: @diegoveloper So if I understood correctly: in that case in the 2nd example when I call HomeActivity() from main.dart, I'm passing the context from the MaterialApp in main.dart to build method in HomeAcitivty.dart right?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Okay great, Thank you very much @diegoveloper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, this issue seems to be a duplicate of this post: ["Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/)

The reason why the error is thrown is because the `Navigator` is unable to access the `Navigator` from the `MaterialApp`. To solve this issue, you can either declare MaterialApp and initialize HomeActivity - like what you're doing, or you can add a `Builder` after initializing MaterialApp inside HomeActivity.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomeActivity();
  }
}

class HomeActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // call Builder to access Navigator from MaterialApp
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home")),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => AddGameActivity())),
                child: new Icon(Icons.add))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddGameActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("AddGame")),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new AddGameActivity())),
              child: new Icon(Icons.add)));
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]