# Navigating to a new screen from AppLifecycleState.resumed event?

Tags: flutter, lockscreen

I'm trying to start a new screen within an AppLifecycleState event, but nothing happens. That's because there is [no context available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator/57924060) in this event that would contain Navigator.

The app must open LockScreen each time the app comes back from resume state (AppLifecycleState.resumed). The most simple case is a banking app that is protected with lock screen each time it's opened.

How to show new screen no matter where you are in code?

My code that does not work:

```
import 'package:alarm_prevozi/screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:alarm_prevozi/screens/lock_screen/lock_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:alarm_prevozi/helpers/translations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  // Then start the application
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  BuildContext myContext;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Listen for when the app enter in background or foreground state.
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // user returned to our app
      _showLockScreenDialog();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // app is inactive
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // user is about quit our app temporally
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.suspending) {
      // app suspended (not used in iOS)
    }
  }

  // Main initialization
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

          return MaterialApp(
            localizationsDelegates: [
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            // Tells the system which are the supported languages
            supportedLocales: translationService.supportedLocales(),
            home: HomeScreen()
          );
  }

  void _showLockScreenDialog() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PassCodeScreen();
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a stream to handle the resume "event".
Since your observer is above the MaterialApp, you don't have a Navigator in your MyApp context, so you need to use a GlobalKey to access the Navigator provided by the MaterialApp.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  StreamController<bool> _showLockScreenStream = StreamController();
  StreamSubscription _showLockScreenSubs;
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    _showLockScreenSubs = _showLockScreenStream.stream.listen((bool show){
      if (mounted && show) {
        _showLockScreenDialog();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    _showLockScreenSubs?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Listen for when the app enter in background or foreground state.
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // user returned to our app, we push an event to the stream
      _showLockScreenStream.add(true);
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // app is inactive
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // user is about quit our app temporally
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      // detached from any host views
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      ...
    );
  }

  void _showLockScreenDialog() {
    _navigatorKey.currentState.
        .pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PassCodeScreen();
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But this still producess Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer. I think this is a good case to use GlobalKeys. Not recommended to use them too much around your app though.

Comment: With the GlobalKey solution, you could pretty much skip the StreamController part. I leave that choice to you.