# How to change current page when app is inactive?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to redirect user to auth page when app is inactive for 5 minutes. I suppose using `WidgetsBindingObserver`. I detect when app is inactive for 5 minutes, but i don't know how to redirect user to auth page.

Here's part of my code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    homeScreen = widget.homeScreen;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          setState(() {
            // navigate to auth page
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Navigator`:

```
Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AuthPage()));
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working. I got error: "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.".

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator/51292613#51292613

Comment: it works, thank you. but now i need to check app state in every page of app :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need redirect an app in 5 minutes, you can redirect it when user want to navigate into page (or to do some action) which needed to be authenticated, just log last action timestamp into SharedPreferences and check this timestamp on every needed-auth action.

Comment: nope, i need to redirect an app. This is the project requirement.