# Exception : Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter, exception, routes, navigator

This error has a lot of solutions. But I am getting this error.  I tried several ways at this site. but could not get a solution. This is my code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 // TODO: implement build
 SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

 return MaterialApp(
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/homepage': (context) => MyApp(),
    '/loginpage': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage()
  },
  home: Scaffold (
    body: Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loginpage');
        },
        child: Image(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/icon.png'),
        ),
      )

    ),

  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: use [MaterialApp.navigatorKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html) property

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `Scaffold` with a `Builder` widget and it will provide you a context.

Here is the updated code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

return MaterialApp(
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/homepage': (context) => MyApp(),
    '/loginpage': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage()
  },
  home: Builder(
    builder:(context)=>Scaffold (
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loginpage');
          },
          child: Image(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/icon.png'),
          ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because the context you are using it doesn't have a material app which is needed for the navigator to work, the context used in `build` widget is from the parent that got sent to it's child so in this case the parent is your main app class which it doesn't have a material app, so you can either use the `Builder` widget as suggested in one of the answers or you can create a separate widget and assign it to the `home` parameter, like this:

your statless widget:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loginpage');
            },
            child: Image(
              width: 100.0,
              height: 100.0,
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/icon.png'),
            ),
          )

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

using it as the home parameter
`home: MyHomePage()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer at this link

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator
```