# Navigation in flutter without context

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a service folder and made a file in it called request. dart, here I intend to place all requests I make into a class called AuthService, with the login request below I want to be able to navigate to the home screen once response.statusCode == 200 or 201 but I am unable to do that because navigation requires a context and my class is neither a Stateful nor Stateless widget, is there any way I can navigate without the context??

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthService {

  login(email, password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (email == "" && password == "") {
      return;
    }

    try {
      Map data = {'email': email, 'password': password};

      var jsonResponse;
      var response = await http
          .post('https://imyLink.com/authenticate', body: data);
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {

//I want to navigate to my home screen once the request made is successful

        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        if (jsonResponse != null) {
          await sharedPreferences.setString("userToken", jsonResponse["token"]);
          var token = sharedPreferences.getString("userToken");
          print('Token: $token');
          print(jsonResponse);
          print("Login successful");
        }
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        print('Login Unsuccessful');
        print(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*OPTION 1*

If you will be calling the `login` method in either a `Stateful` or `Stateless` widget. You can pass `context` as a parameter to the `login` method of your `AuthService` class.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
class AuthService {

  // pass context as a parameter
  login(email, password, context) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (email == "" && password == "") {
      return;
    }

    try {
      Map data = {'email': email, 'password': password};

      var jsonResponse;
      var response = await http
          .post('https://imyLink.com/authenticate', body: data);
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {

      //I want to navigate to my home screen once the request made is successful
      Navigator.of(context).push(YOUR_ROUTE); // new line

        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        if (jsonResponse != null) {
          await sharedPreferences.setString("userToken", jsonResponse["token"]);
          var token = sharedPreferences.getString("userToken");
          print('Token: $token');
          print(jsonResponse);
          print("Login successful");
        }
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        print('Login Unsuccessful');
        print(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

*OPTION 2*

You can access your app's Navigator without a context by setting the navigatorKey property of your MaterialApp:

```
  /// A key to use when building the [Navigator].
  ///
  /// If a [navigatorKey] is specified, the [Navigator] can be directly
  /// manipulated without first obtaining it from a [BuildContext] via
  /// [Navigator.of]: from the [navigatorKey], use the [GlobalKey.currentState]
  /// getter.
  ///
  /// If this is changed, a new [Navigator] will be created, losing all the
  /// application state in the process; in that case, the [navigatorObservers]
  /// must also be changed, since the previous observers will be attached to the
  /// previous navigator.
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
```

Create the key:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Pass it to MaterialApp:

```
new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      navigatorKey: key,
    );
```

Push routes (both named and non-named routes work):

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/someRoute');
```

Find more details about option 2 by following the github issue below: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074

Comment: Happy Fluttering :)

Comment: from where on earth this `generateRoute` coming from?

Comment: @PeakGen Did you mean [the `onGenerateRoute` property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html)? "The Navigator is only built if `onGenerateRoute` is not null; if it is null, `navigatorKey` must also be null."

Answer (score 20):

First, create a class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationService{
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey;

  static NavigationService instance = NavigationService();

   NavigationService(){
     navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
   }

  Future<dynamic> navigateToReplacement(String _rn){
return navigationKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed(_rn);
  }
 Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String _rn){
   return navigationKey.currentState.pushNamed(_rn);
  }
 Future<dynamic> navigateToRoute(MaterialPageRoute _rn){
   return navigationKey.currentState.push(_rn);
  }

 goback(){
   return navigationKey.currentState.pop();

  }
  }
```

In your main.dart file.

```
 MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: NavigationService.instance.navigationKey,
  initialRoute: "login",
  routes: {
    "login":(BuildContext context) =>Login(),
    "register":(BuildContext context) =>Register(),
    "home":(BuildContext context) => Home(),

  },
);
```

Then you can call the function from anywhere in your project like...

```
 NavigationService.instance.navigateToReplacement("home");
 NavigationService.instance.navigateTo("home");
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and clean solution without any plugin/package.

1. Create global variable:

   ```
   final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
   ```
2. Add this global key to the MaterialApp:

   ```
    child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          navigatorKey: navKey,
        ));
   ```
3. Now you have 2 ways to use it. Either define routes and use route names or use non-named route (this is the only way if you do not want to use global variables and pass parameters directly to a widget).

a) Option 1. Define routes and then use route names:

```
// Define route names
MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      navigatorKey: navKey,
routes: {
            "login": (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
            "register": (BuildContext context) => RegisterPage(),

    );

// Now anywhere inside your code change widget like this without context:
navKey.currentState?.pushNamed('login');
```

b) Option 2. Push non-named routes to the navigator:

```
navKey.currentState?.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage()));
```

This way allows to pass parameters directly to widget without global variable:

```
navKey.currentState?.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage('yourStringValue', 32)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter `Get` package.

[Here is link](https://pub.dev/packages/get).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin to skip the required context

https://pub.dev/packages/one_context

```
// go to second page using named route
OneContext().pushNamed('/second');
// go to second page using MaterialPageRoute
OneContext().push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage()));
// go back from second page
OneContext().pop();
```

But make sure you initialize properly in material app.

```
    navigatorKey: OneContext().navigator.key,
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to use S.R Keshav method to access pages and giving them an argument ?

```
routes: {
 "sce": (BuildContext context, {args}) => MatchConversation(args as int),
 "passport": (BuildContext context, {dynamic args}) => Passport(),
},
```

It looks that the arg is lost when Navigator goes in _pushEntry method. The navigated Page is accessed, but no initial arguments are loaded.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do that, the code snippet you posted, doesn't it work there?

Comment: You can try asking this as a seperate question to get answers faster if you haven't

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31637019)

Comment: I finally used OneContext(), did not find a way to pass args with the routes.