# Why do we need to push the context of our previous screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Why do we need to *push* the **context of our previous screen** in **flutter**?
Would we need this in order to keep track of the previous branch of the tree?

Why this is not working? I want to know the reason why this code is not working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    FirstRoute(),
  );
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation Basics',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('First Route'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            child: Text('Open route'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: Text("Second Route"),
                    ),
                    body: Center(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text('Go back!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to break up your `BuildContext` into separate classes.  And it's always good practice to split up different pages into different classes anyways.  But not just different classes but an entirely different file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    FirstRoute(),
  );
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation Basics',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.amberAccent,
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (childContext) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text("Second Route"),
                  ),
                  body: Center(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text('Go back!'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yea I know this but I want to know a good reason for this.

Comment: It's because `FirstRoute` is the parent of the `MaterialApp` which doesn't include a navigator as part of it's `BuildContext`.  Since it's the parent, it doesn't know that it needs navigation.  When you separate out the page `HomePage` into another widget, then it can figure out it needs a navigator.  A much more detailed explanation can be found here if this doesn't make sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51292613/3705348