# My text widget not showing when I use MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

*Question*
When I used MaterialPageRoute my Text Widget in page 2 isn't showing.
What I do here wrong?

*My main page*

```
class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
              },
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                'Page 1',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              )),
            )));
  }
}
```

*Page2* (The message that I print "Moved to page 1" printed to the screen actually.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var black = Colors.black;
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            print("Moved to page 1");
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Page 2',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think ur program is correct. "Page 1" and "Page 2" will be shown on the app and "Moved to page 1" will be shown on the terminal.

Comment: I still wonder why I cant see the text widget in Page2

Comment: You have set the font size to 2 for the text in the page 2. It's so small to be seen. Increase the font size and you'll see. Set minimum 12

Comment: @OMiShah you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the home body and put it inside a new class like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Page1());
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('a');
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
          },
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Page 1',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              )),
        ));
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var black = Colors.black;
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            print("Moved to page 1");
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Page 2',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

This is happening due to the context that you are passing to navigator.
For more info you can read this
[Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator/51292613#51292613)