# Flutter Drawer won't close on tap with Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter

I have been playing around with the drawer and the items inside change some buttons in the body of the scaffold.

What can I do to have this drawer close when the user clicks on an item?

I have used the `Navigator.POP(context);` however it will not close the drawer.

Here is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _modIndex = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(child: Text('Choose a mod'),),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Wheels'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _modIndex = 0;
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Suspension'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _modIndex = 1;
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Body Colour'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _modIndex = 2;
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
      ...
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> this error can still happens when you use a context that is a parent of MaterialApp/WidgetApp.
> This happens because when you do Navigator.of(context), it will start from the widget associated to the context used. And then go upward in the widget tree until it either find a Navigator or there's no more widget. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51292613/10157127)

Separate `MaterialApp` from `Home` widget, means create another widget to have context.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomeWidget());
  }
}


class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  int _modIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("title"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("_modIndex $_modIndex "),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Choose a mod'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Wheels'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _modIndex = 0;
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Suspension'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _modIndex = 1;
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Body Colour'),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _modIndex = 2;
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although I now get a black screen after an item in the drawer is tapped.

Comment: Commented 1st option , check update

Comment: I wrote out the code myself so I always had the `_modIndex` uncommented. I still had the back screen though.

Comment: Are you talking about the  body? It is because there is no `body` or `appBar` on `homePahe`, include those on `Scaffold`. check update

Comment: Yeah, everything looks as it should, I have Scaffold set up with the app bar, etc.  The problem is when I now click an item in the drawer, the screen goes black.

Comment: `screen goes black` means drawer close event?

Comment: Yes? After a hot reload I get a red screen error. "Failed assertion: line 5339 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true."

Comment: do a `flutter clean` and rebuild the app again,

Comment: How do I do perform a flutter clean? I'm so sorry I'm really new to this.

Comment: on terminal  type `flutter clean` and run the app again, and can you include what are you trying to archive

Answer (score 0):

First create a ScaffoldState key

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,)
```

Now you can close the drawer using the `closeDrawer()` method.

```
closeDrawer() async {
  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
  }
}
```