# Null check operator used on a null value Error

Tags: flutter, dart

**What is the cause of this problem?**
***When I click on the button to show the toast, this message appears***

The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

*When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
showToastWidget (package:flutter_styled_toast/src/styled_toast.dart:268:22)
[image]

```
 home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showToast(txt,
                context: context,
                animation: StyledToastAnimation.slideFromLeft,
                reverseAnimation: StyledToastAnimation.slideToBottom,
                position: StyledToastPosition(
                align: Alignment.bottomCenter, offset: 55),
                animDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
                reverseCurve: Curves.elasticIn,
                backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(191, 21, 35, 0.5),
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white));
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Code Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatelessWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you separate the home `Scaffold` on different widget and try again.

Comment: What is `txt`? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved @YeasinSheikh

Comment: @nvoigt The `txt` is in the image

Comment: you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51292613/10157127)

Answer (score -1):

**Answer :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dialogPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home:DialogPage() ,
    );
  }
}
```

```
   return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showToast(txt,
              context: context,
              animation: StyledToastAnimation.slideFromLeft,
              reverseAnimation: StyledToastAnimation.slideToBottom,
              position: const StyledToastPosition(
                  align: Alignment.bottomCenter, offset: 55),
              animDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
              curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
              reverseCurve: Curves.elasticIn,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(191, 21, 35, 0.5),
              textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Code Sample')),
      body: const Center(
        child: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).