# Why is Flutter not Navigating Based on the main.dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, mobile

I am trying to implement navigation with persistent widgets in Flutter, but calling `Navigation.of(context).pushNamed('/route')` yields a "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator" error.
The code for each of the classes is as follows:

main.dart

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Benchside',
      theme: ThemeData(
            fontFamily: 'GemunuLibre',
      ),
      builder: (context, child) => BaseWidget(content: child!),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const HomePage(),
        '/profile': (context) => const ProfilePage(),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == '/') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomePage());
        }
        else if (settings.name == '/profile') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ProfilePage());
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

BaseWidget.dart

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA),
        body: SafeArea(
          minimum: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: CColumn(children: [

        //HEADER
        AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'BENCHSIDE',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xFA, 0xFA, 0xFA),
          scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {  },
            icon: const Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/setting.png'),
              width: 30.0,
              height: 30.0,
              color: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/announcements.png'),
                  width: 30.0,
                  height: 30.0,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4),
                )
            )
          ],
        ),


    // PAGE VIEWER
        Expanded(child: content,),

        // NAVIGATION BAR
    Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
        ),
        child:
                Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/')},
                    child:
                      const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/home.png'), 
                      width: 30.0, 
                      height: 30.0,
                  ),),
                    Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/ranking.png'), 
                    width: 30.0, 
                    height: 30.0, 
                    color: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4),),
                    Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/community.png'), 
                    width: 30.0, 
                    height: 30.0, 
                    color: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4),),
                                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/profile')},
                    child: const CircleAvatar()
                  ),
        ],),
        )],
    ),),
      );
  }
```

I have tried switching to using a home page instead of an initial route, but that didn't seem to work either.

If you are still confused on what I'm trying to do, here is the [guide](https://medium.com/geekculture/persistent-widget-across-all-screens-using-flutter-navigator-45e6b2e57cf7) I was following.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan No, I spent about an hour going over that, but couldn’t get it to work with initialRoute. The home page is already abstracted to its own class, same with the builder, which is the BaseWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems with `context`.

You need to declare `navigatorKey` in the Material app

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Assign it in `MaterialApp`

```
    return MaterialApp(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
```

and then you can use it as:

```
Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).pushNamed('/profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in order to do what I was attempting to accomplish, I had to use a custom Navigation Service and use Dependency Injection via the "get_it" package.

Specific information can be found [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/navigate-without-context-in-flutter-with-a-navigation-service-e6d76e880c1c)