"Error with context after widget disposal when calling showModalBottomSheet and showDialog in Flutter"
I'm experiencing an issue where I'm trying to show file options in a bottom sheet and a confirmation dialog using showModalBottomSheet and showDialog, but I'm getting the following error:
**Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.**

It seems like the context I am using for these operations is no longer valid after the widget has been disposed. I’ve tried the following approaches but the issue persists.
What I’ve tried:
1. Using onLongPress within ListView.builder
I am passing the context from the itemBuilder method of a ListView.builder.
I use this context to show a modal bottom sheet and dialog, but after some operations, I get the error about the context being disposed.
2. Calling showModalBottomSheet:
I’m using showModalBottomSheet to show the file options after a long press on a ListTile:
    await showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  backgroundColor: theme.cardColor,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
  ),
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        // ListTile options here
      ],
    );
  },
);


Calling showDialog:

Inside the bottom sheet, I use showDialog to show a confirmation alert dialog for file deletion. This context is passed from the bottom sheet context as well:
final confirmDelete = await showDialog<bool>(
  context: context,
  builder: (dialogContext) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Delete File'),
      content: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete this file?'),
      actions: [
        // Actions here
      ],
    );
  },
);


Attempting to use SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback:

Since context issues arise during asynchronous operations, I tried using SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback to ensure the context is stable before performing actions like file deletion:
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  await fileProvider.deleteFile(userId, folderId, fileId);
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(content: Text('File deleted successfully')),
  );
});

Current Issue:
Despite these efforts, I am still getting the error about the context being disposed of when performing actions like showing the showModalBottomSheet or showDialog.
This issue appears when the widget has been disposed (e.g., when navigating away from the current screen or after performing an async operation).
What I’ve tried to fix it:

Moved context calls inside addPostFrameCallback to ensure the
context is stable.
Used showModalBottomSheet and showDialog
correctly, but it still doesn’t seem to avoid the context disposal
issue.

Is there a better way to handle context stability when using modals or dialogs in asynchronous Flutter operations?

Your attempts to fix the error have nothing to do with the listed error. The error doesn't state the context is gone but that it doesn't have a Navigator, which is a completely different issue. I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator
