# Flutter hold splash screen for 3 Seconds. How to implement splash screen in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, splash-screen

How to show splash screen in flutter for 3 seconds and then go next my login screen.

I have tried.countdowntimer but import is unresolved

```
import 'package: countDown/countDown.dart';
CountDown cd  =  new CountDown(new Duration(seconds: 4));
CountDown is unresolved
```

Android Studio & Flutter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can execute code with a delay using `Future.delayed`

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
});
```

**update**

```
const delay = 3;
widget.countdown = delay;

StreamSubscription sub;
sub = new Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (count) {
  setState(() => widget.countdown--);  
  if(widget.countdown <= 0) {
    sub.cancel();
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
  }
});
```

Comment: But for countdown time what have to do?

Comment: Why not? . . . .

Comment: Because you have to manually update the countdown. If you wanted to display seconds/milliseconds you'd have to change the refresh tick. 

Using a `AnimationController` with the duration of your countdown combined with a `AnimatedBuilder` will allow more flexibility while not having to bother with refresh.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: where should I call this future code . I mean i don't want to onClick

Comment: You can use `initState` of `AppWidget` (somewhat depending on how your code and widgets are structured)

Comment: @RémiRousselet Do you know why the comment with a link to your answer was removed?

Comment: I removed it. In the end considering he ask for a countdown, it's not really a duplicate.

Comment: You can still add it as comment for reference or adapt it and post another answer here.

Comment: I think best solution will be this only for splash . =   new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), goToLogin);. Where gotoLogin(){}

Comment: @DeepakKanyan what would be the advantage of that? Especially with the update that the screen should be updated periodically (every second)?

Comment: @RémiRousselet great. Didn't see :D

Answer (score 35):

> Simple solution which i use in every app.

Use `Timer` class in build method 
code snippet

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Splash createState() => Splash();
}

class Splash extends State<SplashScreen>  {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Timer(
            Duration(seconds: 3),
                () =>
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => LandingScreen())));


    var assetsImage = new AssetImage(
        'images/new_logo.png'); //<- Creates an object that fetches an image.
    var image = new Image(
        image: assetsImage,
        height:300); //<- Creates a widget that displays an image.

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        /* appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MyApp"),
          backgroundColor:
              Colors.blue, //<- background color to combine with the picture :-)
        ),*/
        body: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: new Center(
            child: image,
          ),
        ), //<- place where the image appears
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I press back button. Wouldn't I come back to the splash screen?

Comment: What is the current situation when you press back button ? Can you tell me so I can update answer

Comment: Its okay now. I wasn't aware about the `pushReplacement()` method. But I did a weird thing. In main.dart, I defined `LandingScreen()` and then in its `initState()`, I did `pushReplacement` to `SplashScreen()`. SplashScreen have this code You provided here. I was trying to achieve this without changing the home: in `main.dart`. It ended up in all kinds of error.

Comment: Okay I got you.. I provided the first screen after main ..if you want me to provide main.dart class also I can update code as well

Comment: I understand what you did and I made it working now.

Comment: I know this is off topic, but while the splash screen is being displayed. Can I fetch json data in background?

Comment: You need to use a background plugin to do task in background ,but background plugin might not work in IOS ,you if I had to get data in background I would have just looked for any other way

Answer (score 20):

refer bellow `main.dart`

```
import 'dart:async';    
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
import 'src/login_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          Divider(
            height: 240.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          new Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
            width: 170.0,
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 105.2,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will helps you

Answer (score 4):

`Future.delayed` would be a good solution *without* a countdown.

But considering you have a countdown, you can use the animation framework Flutter provides.

The idea behind it would be to use an `AnimationController` with a duration of 3 seconds. Start the animation as soon as the splashScreen is instantiated. And add a listener to redirect to `/login` on animation end.

Then pass that controller to an `AnimationBuilder` which would handle the formating of your countdown based on `animationController.lastElaspedDuration`.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Duration duration;

  const SplashScreen({this.duration});

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = new AnimationController(duration: widget.duration, vsync: this)
      ..forward()
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
        }
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (context, _) {
        return new Center(
          child: new Text(animationController.lastElapsedDuration.inSeconds.toString()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed a widget with 5 seconds delay. My solution was as following:

```
class Waiting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WaitingState createState() => _WaitingState();
}

class _WaitingState extends State<Waiting> {
  bool voxt = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
      builder: (c, s) => s.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
          ? Text('Waiting')
          : Text('3 sec passed')
    );
  }
}
```

Now **Waiting** widget can be called where needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a `splashScreen` within a `StatlessWidget()`. Inside the `MaterialApp()` under home:

```
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (ctx, timer) => timer.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? ProfileScreen() //Screen to navigate to once the splashScreen is done.
            : Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/download.png'),
                ),
              )),
```

Answer (score 1):

**The cleanest approach without adding explicit timers.**

Use Time based `SplashScreen`.

```
class TimeBasedSplash extends State<MyApp>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 10,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new HomeScreen(),// Where to navigate after 10 secs
      image: new Image.asset('assets/images/flutter_logo.png'),
      photoSize: 200,
      loaderColor: Colors.white,
      styleTextUnderTheLoader : const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
     loadingText: new Text('Loading...'),
      gradientBackground: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: <Color>[
          Colors.lightBlue,
          Colors.indigo
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

In main class

```
void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TimeBasedSplash().build(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clear the old activity from stack (Splash Screen), So you have to use [`pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html) instead of using `pushNamed` only.

```
  new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/login', ModalRoute.withName('/'));
});
```

Comment: Or use `pushReplacementNamed`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is applicable only in case you are using `flutter-redux`.

Along with `flutter-redux` you need to use `redux-persist` library to show loading screen.

`redux-persist` is used to store, rehydrate app state.

**Example:**

**1.main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';
import 'package:redux_persist_flutter/redux_persist_flutter.dart';

import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/presentation/platform_adaptive.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/screens/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/store/store.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/middleware/middleware.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/models/app_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/routes.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    final store = createStore();

    MyApp();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new PersistorGate(
            persistor: persistor,
            loading: new LoadingScreen(),
            builder: (context) => new StoreProvider<AppState>(
                store: store,
                child: new MaterialApp(
                    title: 'Flutter test App',
                    theme: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                        ? kIOSTheme
                        : kDefaultTheme,
                routes: getRoutes(context, store),
                    initialRoute: '/login',
                )
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

**2.store.dart**

```
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';

import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/reducers/app_reducer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/models/app_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux_starter/middleware/middleware.dart';

Store<AppState> createStore() { 
    Store<AppState> store = new Store(
        appReducer,
        initialState: new AppState(),
        middleware: createMiddleware(),
    );
    persistor.start(store);

    return store;
}
```

In createStore you can use Future.delayed to delay the creation of store for certain no of seconds.

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
 // 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future.delayed` constructor in your `initState`. This will keep your SplashScreen for the duration you specify before the navigation happen.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState (){
    super.initState();
    // TODO initial state stuff
    new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //build
  }
}
```

I only copied the answers from:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669025/flutter-splash-screen)

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach for splash screen, the advantage of this approach is to make sure that the splash screen launch only once when the app starting.

First define a static bool in app home class to indicate the app launch.

```
static bool launch = true;
```

Then at the home attribute in your MaterialApp widget at app home class, check if (launch) is true use a FutureBuilder to launch the splash screen, if (launch) is false set home to your second screen. With FutureBuilder you can set a timer for your splash screen, when it done your second screen will start (credit to O'neya answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699447/11619215).

```
home: launch? FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (ctx, timer) =>
        timer.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')
            : appSplashScreen(),
      ): const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
```

In the Second screen, check if (launch) is true then set it to false. This will make sure that the splash screen will only launch once each time your application start.

```
if(AppHome.launch) {
      AppHome.launch = false;
    }
```

Below is the full code with appSplashScreen widget at the bottom:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const AppHome());
}

class AppHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //static bool to indicate the launching of the app
  static bool launch = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: launch? FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (ctx, timer) =>
        timer.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')
            : appSplashScreen(),
      ): const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //mack sure your splash screen only launch once at your app starting
    if(AppHome.launch) {
      AppHome.launch = false;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'My Second screen',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget appSplashScreen() {
  return Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      ////you can add background image/color to your splash screen
      // image: DecorationImage(
      //   image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
      //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
      // ),
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        //get MediaQuery from instance of window to get height and width (no need of context)
        height: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.height*0.5,
        width: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width*0.5,
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            ////you can add image to your splash screen
            // Image(
            //   image: AssetImage('assets/splashscreen_image.png'),
            // ),
            FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  'Loading',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                )
            ),
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```