# Create a countdown timer that prints a remaining time every 5 seconds for each value in a list

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in Flutter that prints the remaining time *every 5 seconds* until the timer runs out, and then runs the same countdown timer for the next value in a list of values.

The following recursive function gets close, but it waits the "iteration" before going to the next value in the `List` even when there is less time remaining for that `Timer`.

```
import 'dart:async';

Future main() async {
  final _sequence = [21, 10, 8];
  final _iteration = 5;

  void _countdown(seq) async {
    if (seq.length > 0) {
      var duration = seq[0];
      print('Starting at $duration');
      Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: _iteration), (timer) {
        var remaining = duration - timer.tick * _iteration;
        if (remaining >= 0) {
          print('$duration, $remaining');
        } else {
          timer.cancel();
          _countdown(seq.sublist(1));
        }
      });
    }
  }

  _countdown(_sequence);
}
```

Each time it runs the duration is defined by the value in the `_sequence` List.

Even using the `CountdownTimer` (instead of `Timer.periodic`) has the same problem with waiting too long when the value remaining is less than the iteration:

```
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

main() {
  final _sequence = [21, 10, 8];
  final _iteration = 5;

  void _countdown(seq) {
    if (seq.length > 0) {
      var duration = seq[0];
      print('Starting at $duration');
      CountdownTimer countdownTimer = CountdownTimer(
        Duration(seconds: duration),
        Duration(seconds: _iteration),
      );

      var sub = countdownTimer.listen(null);
      sub.onData((timer) {
        if (timer.remaining > Duration(seconds: 0)) {
          print('$duration, ${timer.remaining.inSeconds}');
        } else {
          sub.cancel();
          _countdown(seq.sublist(1));
        }
      });
    }
  }

  _countdown(_sequence);
}
```

The results should look like this with a 5 second pause between lines except where noted:

```
Starting at 21
21, 16
21, 11
21, 6
21, 1          <-- This one should only pause 1 second before continuing
Starting at 10
10, 5
10, 0          <-- This one should immediately continue
Starting at 8
8, 3           <-- This one should only pause 3 seconds before continuing
```

Comment: Can you explain when will the timer run out? what is your duration

Comment: Than I will make an answer, once I understand better what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter hold splash screen for 3 Seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129761/flutter-hold-splash-screen-for-3-seconds)

Answer (score 6):

Dart/Flutter supports countdown with CountDownTimer. Below are 2 examples, one without UI and one with a simple Text at center of screen (The timeout = 10 seconds and the step = 1 seconds, you can change to whatever you want)

**Example 1:**

```dart
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

void main() {
  const timeOutInSeconds = 10;
  const stepInSeconds = 2;
  int currentNumber = 0;

  CountdownTimer countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
      new Duration(seconds: timeOutInSeconds),
      new Duration(seconds: stepInSeconds));

  var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
  sub.onData((duration) {
    currentNumber += stepInSeconds;
    int countdownNumber = timeOutInSeconds - currentNumber;
    // Make it start from the timeout value
    countdownNumber += stepInSeconds;
    print('Your message here: $countdownNumber');
  });

  sub.onDone(() {
    print("I'm done");

    sub.cancel();
  });
}
```

**Example 2:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new CountdownTimerPage()));
}

class CountdownTimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CountdownTimerPageState createState() => new CountdownTimerPageState();
}

class CountdownTimerPageState extends State<CountdownTimerPage> {
  final timeOutInSeconds = 10;
  final stepInSeconds = 2;
  int currentNumber = 0;

  CountdownTimerPageState() {
    setupCountdownTimer();
  }

  setupCountdownTimer() {
    CountdownTimer countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
        new Duration(seconds: timeOutInSeconds),
        new Duration(seconds: stepInSeconds));

    var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
    sub.onData((duration) {
      currentNumber += stepInSeconds;

      this.onTimerTick(currentNumber);
      print('Your message here: $currentNumber');
    });

    sub.onDone(() {
      print("I'm done");

      sub.cancel();
    });
  }

  void onTimerTick(int currentNumber) {
    setState(() {
      currentNumber = currentNumber;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int number = timeOutInSeconds - currentNumber;
    // Make it start from the timeout value
    number += stepInSeconds;
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
          child: new Text(
        "Your message here: $number",
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25.0),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach.  How is the "remaining" time accessed?  Instead of printing the numberOfMessage, the objective is to print the remaining time.

Comment: I created an example here: https://github.com/nextfunc/flutter-playground. Please check it and let me know

Comment: @Simpler I just updated my answer also. If it helps, you can vote and accept. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this methods doesn't work when the increment (stepInSeconds) is something other than 1 second.  Set the increment to 2.  The desired output would be:  10, 8, 6, 4, 2.

Comment: Haha, sorry. I updated the code one more time. @Simpler

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

[image: Demo]

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'NonStopIO',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _sequence = [10, 10, 8];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer(0);
  }

  startTimer(int index) async {
    if (index < _sequence.length) {
      print("Sequence $index - countdown :  ${_sequence[index]} ");
      new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
        if ((_sequence[index] / 5) >= timer.tick) {
          print("${_sequence[index] - timer.tick * 5}");
        } else {
          timer.cancel();
          startTimer(index + 1);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('NonStopIO'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'Counter',
            ),
            new Text(
              '',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Start the periodic timer which prints something every 5 seconds
Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
  print('Something');
});

// Stop the periodic timer using another timer which runs only once after specified duration
new Timer(new Duration(minutes: 1), () {
  timer.cancel();
});
```

Comment: Nice, but a separate timer to cancel the first timer seems odd.

Comment: As of my knowledge this will be the best and simple solution for your problem.

Comment: Can I access the time remaining so that it can be printed in the print statement?

Comment: Just give me a minute I'll try to figure out if there is some other way

Answer (score 2):

I found another answer which satisfies your requirements i think. Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {

    new CountdownTimer(new Duration(minutes: 1), new Duration(seconds: 5)).listen((data) {
      print('Something');
      print('Remaining time: ${data.remaining.inSeconds}');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems similar to my solution above :)

Comment: Sorry for that. I read your answer just now. It wasn't intensional.

Comment: Why is the ${data.remaining.inSeconds} not in increments defined in the CountdownTimer?  In this example, I would expect to see it countdown from 60, 55, 50, 45, etc., but it is more sporadic.