# How to set splash screen time out on flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, rive

I am new to flutter and am kinda lost on how to set up a time to my splash screen so after this time it goes to the main screen. am using rive for the splash screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';
void main() {
 runApp(const MaterialApp(home: SimpleAnimation()));
}
class SimpleAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
 const SimpleAnimation({Key? key, this.loading}) : super(key: key);
 final bool? loading;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return const Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: RiveAnimation.asset('assets/splash/splash.riv',
         fit: BoxFit.cover)
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set 3 second time in initstate after navigate to which screen you want

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    
    // after 3 second it will navigate
    
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((val) {
      // Navigation Here
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      // your code
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  @override
void initState() { 
//set timer for splash screen
Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), () async {
//add your logic here 
 Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context, ScreenRoute.mainScreen, (route) => false);
super.initState();
}
```

Comment: please up the votes if it help you.

Answer (score 2):

This `SimpleAnimation` widget shows after the splash screen.  While this is `StatelessWidget` widget, you can define method inside `build` method. Change  `Duration(seconds: 2)` based on your need.

```dart
class SimpleAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const NextScreen(),
          ));
    });
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
```

Comment: While this approach is for sure the simplest one, it has one bug - the build method might be called several times (to reproduce it - just rotate the device), and each time a new Future will be created, so there might be a situation when navigation will happen several times.

Comment: `StatelessWidget` doesn't rebuild on orientation changes, I've just recheck it.

Comment: True, my bad. According to documentation, "the build method of a stateless widget is typically only called in three situations: the first time the widget is inserted in the tree, when the widget's parent changes its configuration, and when an InheritedWidget it depends on changes.". I thought that orientation change might be a "configuration" case. Though the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

As folks already mentioned the straighforward way would be to add a delay and do navigation after it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const MainScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ColoredBox(color: Colors.green);
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ColoredBox(color: Colors.yellow);
  }
}
```

Though, with this implementation, you'll have to depend on the animation length. So when you'll update animation - you'll have not to forget to update it inside the splash screen. A more reliable (and complex) solution would be to listen to the animation status and do the navigation after the animation finishes. Like this (warning, change ):

```dart
class PlayOneShotAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayOneShotAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayOneShotAnimationState createState() => _PlayOneShotAnimationState();
}

class _PlayOneShotAnimationState extends State<PlayOneShotAnimation> {
  late RiveAnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = OneShotAnimation(
      'bounce',
      autoplay: true,
      onStop: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute<void>(
            builder: (context) => const MainScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RiveAnimation.network(
          'https://cdn.rive.app/animations/vehicles.riv',
          animations: const ['idle', 'curves'],
          controllers: [_controller],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ColoredBox(color: Colors.yellow);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach for splash screen, the advantage of this approach is to make sure that the splash screen launch only once when the app starting.

First define a static bool in app home class to indicate the app launch.

```
static bool launch = true;
```

Then at the home attribute in your MaterialApp widget at app home class, check if (launch) is true use a FutureBuilder to launch the splash screen, if (launch) is false set home to your second screen. With FutureBuilder you can set a timer for your splash screen, when it done your second screen will start (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699447/11619215).

```
home: launch? FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (ctx, timer) =>
        timer.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')
            : appSplashScreen(),
      ): const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
```

In the Second screen, check if (launch) is true then set it to false. This will make sure that the splash screen will only launch once each time your application start.

```
if(AppHome.launch) {
      AppHome.launch = false;
    }
```

Below is the full code with appSplashScreen widget at the bottom:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const AppHome());
}

class AppHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //static bool to indicate the launching of the app
  static bool launch = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: launch? FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (ctx, timer) =>
        timer.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ? const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')
            : appSplashScreen(),
      ): const SecondScreen(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //mack sure your splash screen only launch once at your app starting
    if(AppHome.launch) {
      AppHome.launch = false;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'My Second screen',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget appSplashScreen() {
  return Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      ////you can add background image/color to your splash screen
      // image: DecorationImage(
      //   image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
      //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
      // ),
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        //get MediaQuery from instance of window to get height and width (no need of context)
        height: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.height*0.5,
        width: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size.width*0.5,
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            ////you can add image to your splash screen
            // Image(
            //   image: AssetImage('assets/splashscreen_image.png'),
            // ),
            FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  'Loading',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                )
            ),
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```