# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

Any solution to solve this problem?

**Stacktrace:**

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.
#0      defaultBinaryMessenger.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:73:7)
#1      defaultBinaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:86:4)
#2      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140:62)
#3      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:35)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:f<…>
```

Comment: put this line as your first statement in main() - WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

Answer (score 596, accepted):

This problem is introduced when you upgrade Flutter. 
The reason behind this is you are waiting for some data or running an `async` function inside `main()`.

I was initialising `ScopedModel` inside `main()` and inside that I was awaiting for some data.

There is a very small fix.
Just run `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` inside `void main()` , before you do `runApp()`. Works like a charm!!

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(Delta(
    model: ProductDataModel(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: make sure WidgetFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() is the first line of main(). and then proceed as usual

Comment: What is the potential negative impact of this? Should all flutter applications have that line in the beginning of the `main()` method?

Comment: If you are using async method in main() , you need to add this

Comment: not working for v1.14.4/v1.14.6 break on var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();

Comment: What happens if we don't use this line, while using async methods ?? I don't have any async methods in main(), but i have async methods in MyApp.

Comment: Works like a charm! How did you get to this solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for me , but what is the main problems way we must put widgetFlutterBinding at the top of main fonction? is it only for the main or any other futur fonction can have the same problem?

Comment: impressive how many ppl are copy and pasting the same solution here

Answer (score 107):

This generally happens if you are awaiting on `main()` method. So, the solution would be:

```
void main() {
  // add this, and it should be the first line in main method
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 

  // rest of your app code
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(...),
  );
}
```

Comment: not working - breaks at  join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'mydb.db'),

Answer (score 38):

Not sure if I have the correct answer, but I got the same error after a recent flutter upgrade, and managed to get it to work, so I'm sharing my findings.

Looks like the error might be caused by a recent breaking change:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/flutter-announce/sHAL2fBtJ1Y/mGjrKH3dEwAJ.

As a result, we need to manually change the code as follows:

> - If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during
>     plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the 
>     `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
> - If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in
>     your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.

Alternatively, if you are a newbie like me and struggling to understand the above and [#38464](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/38464), you can temporarily avoid this problem by switching to the beta channel. Just run "flutter channel beta". The breaking change is not in beta channel yet, so after switching to beta channel you wouldn't get this error at least for now.

Answer (score 18):

just add this line in main.dart

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

your code seems like

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  return runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: AppState(),
      )
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You could run into this if you're trying to execute plugin native code in an isolate. The isolate_handler documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler) explains this well:

> Plugins use a mechanism called platform channel to communicate between
>   the Dart and the native sides, a message passing mechanism using the
>   MethodChannel type. This mechanism depends on elements of the
>   underlying UI engine to function.

The catch here is that isolates will provide a performance boost only in the case of computationally expensive dart code. The plugin's platform code will again use the main(UI) thread again.

Calling `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized` inside an isolate will also fail because of the absence of an underlying UI engine in the isolate.

Comment: The workaround is to use [isolate_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler) or [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) to spawn the isolate.

Comment: @jon : This is what the isolate_handler documentation says: `If your tasks are computationally intensive on the Dart side, isolates will help a lot. If the time is spent in the plugin native side, you won't gain much unless you create your own native threads on the native side, in the plugin itself. There is nothing you can do about it in your main Dart app.` So there is no workaround here unless the plugin itself is designed to use multiple threads

Comment: @letiagoalves There is no workaround here as I see from the above docs. If you design a plugin, make sure it is multithreaded.

Answer (score 9):

By adding this line inside `void main()`, the error will be resolved.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Answer (score 7):

**Solution:** Call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` **before** calling asynchronous functions.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   //  ADD THIS BEFORE YOUR ASYNC FUNCTION CALL.
  await Firestore.instance.settings(...);      //  NOW YOU CAN CALL ASYNC FUNCTION.   
  ...
  runApp(
    ...
  )
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved using `WidgetsBinding.ensureInitialized()` which established communication between the `Dart Layer` and `Platform`.

We need to call this method if we need the binding to be initialized before calling [runApp]. Flutter cannot directly interact with the flutter engine until and unless binding is established.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   
  /// Your Code which required binding
  runApp(
    ...
  )
}
```

`WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` supports various binding such as

1. `ServicesBinding` listens for platform messages and directs them to the handler for incoming messages (BinaryMessenger).
2. `PaintingBinding` is responsible for binding to the painting library.
3. `RenderBinding` binds the render tree to the Flutter engine.
4. `WidgetBinding` binds the widget tree to the Flutter engine.
5. `SchedulerBinding` is the scheduler for running immediate tasks.
6. `SemanticsBinding` binds the semantics layer and the Flutter engine.
7. `GestureBinding` is a binding for the gesture subsystem.

These all binding will act as a glue between Dart and Platform.

Answer (score 6):

in my case when using orientation,

> before solved :

```
void main() {
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then((_).{
runApp(MyApp());
});
}
```

> solved use :

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
  .then((_) {
runApp(MyApp());
});
}
```

*The point is to add WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() in the first line of the main class*

Answer (score 4):

It's worth nothing that if you are receiving this error from an isolate, then the accepted solution doesn't work.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

only ensures the binding on the main thread.
There is work being done to be able to remove the restriction, you can follow that issue here

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937

Answer (score 1):

Before I had the version `v1.12.13+hotfix.5`, then I switched to version `v1.14.4` and it worked.

The error says that you should add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`, but since that didn't work for me I switched to the other version. One thing to keep in mind though is that you still have to add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` as the very first line in your main!

Answer (score 0):

An answer posted on the GitHub issue 47033 solved my problem.

issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47033

the solution that worked for me: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47033#issuecomment-571936089

I think this is an issue regarding the flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix maybe downgrading the flutter may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to close the flutter app, and start it up again.

I got this error when I `flutter pub add shared_preferences` then my web browser was trying to hot reload and failed. Stopping the debugging session and starting a new one made everything just work.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem while working on a udemy project [xylophone_flutter](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/xylophone-flutter.git)

My flutter version is 3.16.9

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

And my dart version is 3.2.6

```
  dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6 (stable) (Wed Jan 24 13:41:58 2024 +0000) on "macos_x64"
```

The issue was happening with the code to use `audioplayers`

Fix is to use `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before you initiate your App which attempts to use the AudioPlayer integration.

Below is the full working code.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(XylophoneApp());
}

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Xylophone')),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              player.play(AssetSource('note2.wav'));
            },
            child: Text("Play"),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```