# Force portrait view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried using this code I found on a thread on this site but all that happens is my application loads a white screen. Is there a better way to force portrait view in flutter? Seems like simple thing to set.

```dart
void main() async {
  ///
  /// Force the layout to Portrait mode
  ///
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: LoginScreen(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Is your test device Android or iOS?

Comment: If you are getting a white screen it means you are getting an Exception before the call to `runApp`. What is the exception when you try and debug the app?

Comment: its android....

Comment: ERROR is : E/flutter (27219): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.

Comment: OP @SamCromer is primarily asking: **Is there a better way to force portrait view in flutter?**

The white screen bugfix everyone is pointing out is secondary, and you guys are not explaining why this is the fix. Additionally, nobody is pointing out there's a gotcha for forcing orientation via `SystemChrome`. The gotcha is regarding iPad's Multitasking flag "Require FullScreen" to be set to the non-default value true. As indicated in my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832614/10830091).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code as

```
void main() {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
 [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
 .then((_) => runApp(new MaterialApp(
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         home: LoginScreen(), 
      )));
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

From the exception in the comment:

```
Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized
```

You need to call

```dart
WidgetsBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Before your call to `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

1. Change your code to this:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  ///
  /// Force the layout to Portrait mode
  ///
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: LoginScreen(),
  ));
}
```

2. Open your Xcode project and go to *Target* -> *Deployment Info* -> `Require Full Screen` to `true`. This will reflect in your *ios/Runner/Info.plist* to have the following value:

```
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
```

### Description

Well there are a couple of points to be addressed here:

1. You forgot [`WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html). This IS important since you're "[awaiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57703060/10830091)" on async `main` method.
2. According to [`setPreferredOrientations`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setPreferredOrientations.html)'s documentation, there's a limitation regarding iPad multitasking:

> This setting will only be respected on iPad if multitasking is
>   disabled.

To alleviate #2, from the docs:

> Should you decide to opt out of multitasking you can do this by
>   setting "Requires full screen" to true in the Xcode Deployment Info.