# Error When Forcing Portrait Orientation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to force my Flutter app to only use Portrait mode. My main() method looks like this.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(uiOverlayStyle);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(ALLOWED_ORIENTATIONS)
  .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}
```

Here is the definition of ALLOWED_ORIENTATIONS:

```
const List<DeviceOrientation> ALLOWED_ORIENTATIONS = [
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp
];
```

I just separated all the settings and such to another file to make modifying them later on easier.

When I run this code, I get the following error.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()`
has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly
call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
```

It looks like there is some race condition that's failing. I am just not sure what is causing it. Removing the `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()` line makes the app compile as expected. So, I am thinking the error has something to do with that line.

Any advice?

Comment: https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-3-how-to-force-the-application-to-stick-to-portrait-mode/

Comment: It’s still giving me the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689492/flutter-unhandled-exception-servicesbinding-defaultbinarymessenger-was-accesse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says

> If you're running an application and need to access the binary
>   messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during
>   plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the
>   `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(uiOverlayStyle);
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(ALLOWED_ORIENTATIONS);

  runApp(MyApp());  
}
```