# Error: google_fonts was unable to load font

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use GoogleFonts to test my UI but I'm getting this strange error `error: google_fonts was unable to load font`.

Thats occurs with any single font.

This is my setup
VsCode 
Flutter 1.12.13+hf9
Windows 10

`pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^0.4.0
```

`Code`

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
Text('data2', style: GoogleFonts.mcLaren())
```

`Error`

> I/flutter ( 5069): error: google_fonts was unable to load font
>   McLaren-Regular because the following exception occured I/flutter (
>   5069): Exception: Failed to load font with url:
>   https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/a/ca48a5e17b0201057453d49c4271d139e5824b553505ad1c6fbbd7cbbbf4d1dc.ttf

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows, locale pt-BR)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.44.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

My mistake, I figure out that:

Emulator/device needs internet connectivity.
Google fonts need internet connection on device/emulator.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: That solved my months of struggling. I didn't expect it to solve my problem because I was already using Firebase libraries which needs internet connectivity.

Comment: @Ataberk Flutter project uses different AndroidManifest.xml for different modes(debug, profile and release). The release AndroidMainfest.xml file will not have internet permission. But the debug and profile mode's AndroidManifest.xml file will have coz Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc. That is why in debug mode it would work properly but when you build the app for release, it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: That makes sense but problem exists in ios

Comment: After adding permission mine didnt work until I uninstalled and reinstalled the app again. So you can add the permission and try reinstalling the app

Comment: So this is for IOS you are talking about right @Don

Comment: No ... not iOS, on Android. I dont know for iOS. You can try that too on iOS

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue when setting the global font for the app. I set font style to app Theme like below.

```
void main(){
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: ThemeConstants.themeColorMaterial,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(),
          ),
        ),
     ),
  }
```

The reason is *google_fonts* package works fetch on HTTP. Normally cannot happen async functions in the main method. So that we need to tell main method there are some asynchronous processes happening. For that, we can add the below code inside main method

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

======= after applying solution ========

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //important

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: ThemeConstants.themeColorMaterial,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

resources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57775690/10827515

Answer (score 1):

There could be few possible reasons for it:

1. Have you installed the Google Font library using PubSpec Assist ?https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist. Initially when I installed the plugin using this extension, it did not work (it should work but strangely it did not). So I installed the plugin in the usual way.
2. You need to **restart** your app in order for changes to take place. The changes in pubspec.yaml will not reflect on mere **Hot Reload / Hot Restart**.
3. You can rebuild the app using `flutter clean` first.

Comment: I'm not using `PubSpec Assist`,`flutter clean` and restart all, windows, vscode and the problem continues.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the app from the device and reinstalling it might solve your problem. It solved for me, when i was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For Android and MacOS network permission need to be explicitly added.
And since google-fonts fetches data over the internet, it is required to add it.

Check out this URL: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/networking#platform-notes

[image: Screenshot for how to add internet access on MacOS and Android]

Answer (score 0):

### The following worked for me.

Go to:
`File`
Select
`Invalidate Caches..`
Wait for Dialog and check:

`Clear file ......`
`Clear VCS Log .....`
then press: `Invalidate and Restart`

Wait 5 or 10 minutes and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `^` from the google fonts dependency in your pubspec.yaml file

Change

```
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
```

To

```
  google_fonts: 6.1.0
```

This worked for me