# Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized

Tags: android-studio, flutter

As I am trying to work on a project I have taken the source code from github and opened it in Android Studio. After syncing there is no error in the whole code but when I run the app it shows so many errors:

[image]

These are the errors shown in the app. **I have tried to migrate into AndroidX but that didn't work either**.
So basically can anyone tell me how to run a flutter app downloaded from any other sources like github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue already brought up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689492/flutter-unhandled-exception-servicesbinding-defaultbinarymessenger-was-accesse/57703060#57703060). You should post the code indicated in the console. The important part seems to be line "#6" of the log, with the package flutter_sudoku `lib/main.dart` file at line 17.

And looking at the github repository, indeed, they are making the main function "await" fot the system orientation to be ready here

```
void main() =>  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
    .then((_) {
      runApp(
      BlocProvider(
        bloc: UserDataBloc(),
        child: MyApp(),
      )
  );
});
```

You must call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before the await function

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
    runApp(BlocProvider(
      bloc: UserDataBloc(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ));
  });
}
```