# Share Preferences Cache Unhandeled Exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get some values from a key and when I run the code,. I get an exception:

```
Restarted application in 2,783ms
E/flutter (15641): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: No Implementation Found
E/flutter (15641): #0      SharePreferenceCache.getValue
E/flutter (15641): #1      Settings.getValue
E/flutter (15641): #2      main
E/flutter (15641): <asynchronous suspension>
```

And here is what I'm trying to do in my main file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  await Settings.init(
    cacheProvider: SharePreferenceCache(),
  );
  String iskeyValue = Settings.getValue<String>(
    keyValue,
  );
```

I have already tried `flutter clean` - `flutter pub get` and reinstalling the app

Answer (score 0):

I think that youre missing the 'defaultValue' parameter.

This works for me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_settings_screens/flutter_settings_screens.dart';

String keyValue = 'keyValue';
Future<void> main() async {
  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57689492/flutter-unhandled-exception-servicesbinding-defaultbinarymessenger-was-accesse
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Settings.init(
    cacheProvider: SharePreferenceCache(),
  );
  Settings.setValue(keyValue, 'Hello W!');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Title'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? isKeyValue = Settings.getValue<String>(keyValue, defaultValue: '');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(isKeyValue ?? 'missing value'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```