# Should every screen check for authentication before loading or should it be done only in the main.dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart

This might be a very basic question but I wanted to understand the best practices followed around the industry.

Right now I am doing this in the build method of the `main.dart` file.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot)  {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MainScreen();
          }
          return AuthScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I always do this in `main.dart`, because It's the most important thing in the app, and easy to switch to `AuthScreen` If the token outdated or server is down.

Comment: So just `main.dart` or anywhere else as well?

Comment: this might help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027858/route-guards-in-flutter`

Answer (score 1):

i don't think anything is wrong with this method, i also use something similar for restarting my app, however there is a problem. when you change the route and get unauthorized it won't open main screen ( because you are no longer in Home widget )

you can try these solutions :

use Builder:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
      builder: (context, widget) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, snapshot)  {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return widget;
              }
              return AuthScreen();
            },
          ),
        },
    );
  }
```

it fixes the issue but you may have data in your widget that may be invalid due to Unauthentication so my suggestion is to restart app like this :

```dart
  double appKey = 0;
  @overrdie
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(() {
      setState(() { appKey++; });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      key: Key('$appKey'),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot)  {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return MainScreen();
          }
          return AuthScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

but if you are sure you handle invalid data it's better to listen to `onAuthStateChanged` ( like in code above ) and push `AuthScreen` via navigator and block user from exiting screen using `WillPopScope` widget in `AuthScreen`. It feels better because of transition animation.