# Flutter secure routes with a flutter-fire authentication guard and avoid unnecessary rebuilds

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, stream-builder, flutter-hotreload

I currently face an issue where I route to an authentication guard view as my default route.
My authentication guard view:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models/user.dart';
import '../services/services.module.dart';
import '../widgets/common/async_stream.dart';
import 'landing_screen/landing_screen.dart';
import 'tabs_screen/tab_screen.dart';

/// The [ViewAuthGuard] decides whether to display the [LandingScreenView] or the [TabsScreenView].
class ViewAuthGuard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('ViewAuthGuard build called: $context');
    FirebaseAuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);

    return AsyncStreamWidget<User>(
      stream: authService.onAuthStateChanged,
      child: (User user) => TabsScreenView(),
      emptyWidget: LandingScreenView(),
      loadingWidget: null,
      errorWidget: null,
    );
  }
}
```

and my `AsyncStreamWidget`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../models/base_model.dart';
import '../../error/future_error.dart';
import '../../loading.dart';

class AsyncStreamWidget<T extends BaseModel> extends StatelessWidget {
  final Stream<T> stream;
  final T initialData;

  Widget _loading;
  Widget _empty;
  Widget Function(Object) _error;
  Widget Function(T) child;

  AsyncStreamWidget({
    @required this.stream,
    @required this.child,
    this.initialData,
    Widget loadingWidget,
    Widget emptyWidget,
    Widget Function(Object) errorWidget,
  }) {
    if (loadingWidget == null) {
      _loading = Loading();
    } else {
      _loading = loadingWidget;
    }

    if (errorWidget == null) {
      _error = (Object error) => FutureErrorWidget(error: error);
    } else {
      _error = errorWidget;
    }

    if (emptyWidget == null) {
      _empty = Center(child: Text('No data available.'));
    } else {
      _empty = emptyWidget;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<T>(
      initialData: initialData,
      stream: stream,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<T> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return _loading;
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active: // check if different behavior is needed for active and done
          case ConnectionState.done:
            // error state
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // todo more throughout error checking and specialized error widget
              return _error(snapshot.error);
            }

            // data state
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              T data = snapshot.data;
              return child(data);
            }

            // empty state
            return _empty;
          case ConnectionState.none:
          default:
            print('E: Received Future [$stream] was null or else.');
            return _error('Unknown error.');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The `FirebaseAuthService` wraps the `auth.FirebaseAuth.instance`. My stream is constructed as follows:

```
User _userFromFirebase(auth.User user) {
  if (user == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return User(
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoUrl: user.photoURL,
  );
}

@override
Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
```

I currently provide all my services above the `ViewAuthGuard`.

I wrapped my Material app with a ThemeProvider ChangeNotifier (in case that could be an issue).

My issue is that all widgets below the `ViewAuthGuard` are rebuild and their state is reset. This occurs to me while developing. When a hot reload occurs, all the children are rebuild. The `TabsScreenView` contains the initial navigation for my flutter app and always reset to index zero during development.

**Question:** How do I avoid the unnecessary reloads at this point?

What I tested so far:

- I wrapped my named route for `TabsScreenView` with FutureBuilder / StreamBuilder and set it as the default route ([Route Guards in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027858/route-guards-in-flutter))
- Listening to the stream in `didComponentUpdate` and pushing named routes on User change
- The solution provided above

Please drop me a comment if you need more information, code, console prints or else to support me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself. For anyone interested, this was the process:

The `stream` is the pivot element which decides if the `AsyncStreamWidget` rebuilds its child or not. So I did check if the `stream` changed across hot reloads by printing its `hashCode` attribute (and yes, it did change).

Subsequently, I did change my `ViewAuthGuard` to a `StatefulWidget` and used the `didChangeDependencies` method to store the `stream` in the state.

(I also started instantiating the widgets in the `initState` method and store them in the state as well so that they are created only once.)

---

**EDIT** And I should mention that my `ViewAuthGuard` has no dependencies. So it is not rebuilt due to a change of dependencies.