# Fatal error on Splash Screen, it abruptly stop the application

Tags: android, dart, flutter, splash-screen

I followed [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101776/9437175) and [medium tutorial](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-splash-screen-9f4e05542548) to make Splash Screen of Android version, but when I start the app, it shows Splash Screen a moment and stop the application.

My Splash Screen logo image directoy

[image]

launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/splash_logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.privacyofanimal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = getFlutterView().getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        getFlutterView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(PrivacyOfAnimal());
}

class PrivacyOfAnimal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '동물의 사생활',
      home: Test(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S8+ and I wanna fix this issue. What is the problem?

Error log

> 2019-01-23 16:44:03.443 18922-18922/com.handong.privacyofanimal
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.handong.privacyofanimal, PID: 18922
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.handong.privacyofanimal/com.handong.privacyofanimal.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.handong.privacyofanimal.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.handong.privacyofanimal-rCGlJOS-fSwTgzOMfceE0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.handong.privacyofanimal-rCGlJOS-fSwTgzOMfceE0g==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.handong.privacyofanimal-rCGlJOS-fSwTgzOMfceE0g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.handong.privacyofanimal.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.handong.privacyofanimal-rCGlJOS-fSwTgzOMfceE0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.handong.privacyofanimal-rCGlJOS-fSwTgzOMfceE0g==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.handong.privacyofanimal-rCGlJOS-fSwTgzOMfceE0g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829)

Comment: add the error log to your question, if you don't see the log, open android studio and check the android logcat from there.

Comment: what's your compileSdkVersion on build gradle ?

Comment: Ok, I will check it. Wait a sec

Comment: There are no android error logs too, my compilesdk version is 27

Comment: comment the lines inside public void onGlobalLayout() { and run again

Comment: Where is `public void onGlobalLayout(){}`? `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: Yes , comment the lines inside that method

Comment: `public void onGlobalLayout() {
//        getFlutterView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
//        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      }
    });` same problem no error log

Comment: I found the log and edited the post, plz see

Comment: I solved, it is the problem of package name, sorry for bothering