# Flutter app on start it is showing white screen for few second

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why does my Flutter app show a white screen for few seconds on start? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: It is flutters default splashscreen See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101776/4712391

Comment: If ever there is a black screen or white screen or launch screen dismissed too quickly in iOS using Flutter framework try to use the step mentioned in the https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36365#issuecomment-532072073

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a splash screen to Flutter apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879103/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-apps)

Answer (score 23):

You can use the package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) to add native splash screens for Android and iOS without the manual changes described in other answers.

The package does the manual changes for you.

1 - Depend on it:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.1.4
```

And `flutter pub get`

2 - Configure your splash screen on `pubspec.yaml`:

```
    flutter_native_splash:
      image: assets/images/splash.png
      color: 42a5f5
```

3 - Run the package

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Splash screens are now generated.

Comment: If anyone is looking for example https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/blob/master/example/pubspec.yaml

Comment: this seems to be the best working solution, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22):

If you see the **black** window background of the activity showing until Flutter renders its first frame, add this on your **AndroidManifest**, between **< activity>** ... **< /activity>**

```
<meta-data
       android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
   android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

Comment: this helped me out. but after doing this my status bar is not showing up in all other pages developed in flutter, can you help me out? @silexcorp

Comment: Check the theme in the style.xml file res/values and avoid the full screen (on Android) <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>

Answer (score 6):

**Android** - Now you can change in

**/AndroidStudioProjects/vendowallet/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml**

Something like

```
<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
```

**IOS**

Change the **LaunchImage** in **Assets.xcassets**

Answer (score 1):

Among the files generated with the flutter create command. A splash screen is generated to be shown before the first frame when flutter is rendering widgets to screen. You can modify it to show a custom splash screen of your choice or you can just remove it..

Within the android folder, open up the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

There you can remove the **meta-data** with attribute name **..SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame** tag within activity named **.MainActivity**

You can check the **drawables** folder and **styles.xml** file to modify the splash screen if you want to keep it.

Within these folders there are also comments that explain more..

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating new projects right now, they gave the solution (with commented code in **launch_background.xml**)

Just open the following files through the android directory.

[image]

You will see the following commented code:

[image]

**Just uncomment it and do as following, You can replace your own image by changing drawable name:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Open Android folder and in drawable folder replace your image**

In manifest file there is some code Just uncomment it and do as following.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable           
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
   />
```

Happy coading

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after I had already added in a splash screen. I was getting a white screen as well. It turns out you have to reinstall the app to get rid of any caching and then it should work properly

https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/creating-launch-screens-ios

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I were setting proxy right in flutter.bat file. And it was setting proxy for local machine too. So my ABD can't listen the physical device.

So if you have similar case - try to set no_proxy for local zones or remove proxy at all.

Answer (score -1):

I head the same problem. Even after I added splash screen I got the black screen for the first time loading the app. My solution was to change the flutter channel form stable to beta. To do that open a command prompt

1. Check what channel you are currently on

   ```
   flutter channel
   ```
2. To change the channel type

   ```
   flutter channel [channel name]
   ```
3. After that type

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```

That's what helped me. I hope it helps also someone.

I found the solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37155