# Change Splash Screen Color Programmatically in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, splash-screen

launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_icon" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

---

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <color name="orange">#FF9800</color>
</resources>
```

I change the primary color value in the app dynamically and set theme colors for app. How can I send the primary color value here --> `<color name="orange">#FF9800</color>`

Also what should I do for IOS?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to see different colors in the splash screen each time you launch the app? Or is there a way the user can set the splash screen color of his choice? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: There are different theme colors in my app. I want to change the splash screen background color according to the theme color.

Comment: when does the theme color change, during which action?

Comment: At any time while the application is running. I save the color value to shared preferences

Comment: Have you already found a solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app on start it is showing white screen for few second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168832/flutter-app-on-start-it-is-showing-white-screen-for-few-second)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't change values of an XML file programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of your splash screen, just follow steps :

- in your : app/android/src/main/res/values, add an xml file colors.xml like this :[colors.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0GZw.png)
- edit this file : app/android/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml , like this :
  [launch_background.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIszS.png)

Comment: Question: How can it be changed dynamically (Programmatically)? You don't understand the question. Review again.

Comment: @Djamel I tried the way you have shared the `.xml` file, but the thing is that my `colors.xml` file is not being recognized, I have tried the restart/invalidCaches

Comment: still, my file is not being recognzsed