# black screen come and go before the splash screen in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

i am developing a flutter app and when i open the app a black screen come and go before the splash screen appear.its really annoying. Here is my splash screen code

```
   class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(245, 246, 250, 1),
      body: DelayedReveal(
        delay: Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/logo.png',
            width: 280,
            height: 280,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Here is my main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Folk',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: new SplashScreen(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        // login and resgistration routes
        "/login": (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
        "/phonelogin": (BuildContext context) => new PhoneLogin(),
         "/forgotpw": (BuildContext context) => new ForgotPassword(),
        "/resetpw": (BuildContext context) => new ResetPassword(),
        "/pincode": (BuildContext context) => new PincodeVerify(),
        "/setupstep1": (BuildContext context) => new SetupStepOne(),
        "/setupstep2": (BuildContext context) => new SetupStepTwo(),
        "/setupstep3": (BuildContext context) => new SetupStepThree(),
        "/location": (BuildContext context) => new GetLocation(),
        "/SettingUpScreen": (BuildContext context) => new SettingUpScreen(),

        //homepage routes
        "/home": (BuildContext context) => new Homepage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hope someone would help me to solve this.

> my flutter version is v1.12.13+hotfix.7

i have done a flutter app with the previous version of the flutter sdk (v1.12.13+hotfix.6) and that app didn't give me this error

Comment: Did you configure the native Android and iOS launch screens?

Comment: No i didnt.. should i ?

Comment: Give it a try. It might work!

Comment: could u plz tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Changing the native Android and iOS launch screens has nothing to do with Flutter. It is just the same as changing the launch screen in any native Android or iOS app that does not involve Flutter.

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/a/59727278/7034640