# Flutter - How to remove first white screen when launch application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I launched the application it shows first white screen then back screen then after open splash screen. My Splash screen is taking 2-3 seconds to open. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168832/flutter-app-on-start-it-is-showing-white-screen-for-few-second.

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen

Comment: But I don't want to add the default splash screen because I can't make it custom. With use of default splash screen, I just add one drawable image nothing else more and I couldn't find my QUESTION's answer anywhere so I asked.

Comment: Flutter uses a default splash screen before launching your app, so you have to modify the default screen to remove the white screen. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-2019-real-splash-screens-tutorial-16078660c7a1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app on start it is showing white screen for few second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168832/flutter-app-on-start-it-is-showing-white-screen-for-few-second)

Answer (score 1):

Flutter use a default splash screen before launching your app.
Follow this tutorial -> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen

Comment: With the use of the default splash screen, I just add one drawable image nothing else more. I want to remove that white screen not to set default app icon on that white screen.