# flutter app shows a white screen when I run app by pressing f5 or run button and runs fine by flutter run command

Tags: android, flutter

Let me Clarify the Problem . I am Running a simple flutter app. When I press f5 or press the green Run Button  , the app  stuck showing white screen on a physical device. But when I run the app from command Line "Flutter Run" the app Runs successfully but hot reload doesn't work in the ide!  Case is same in VS Code and Android Studio.
Flutter Doctor! Fine
Flutter Pub get! Fine

Uninstalled the app many times.[[image: This is the screen of my Physical deviceNo Log Errors]s

Comment: I have the same problem, but have a few more details to add: (1) F5 / Green Play Button both produce *Blank Screen*  like the one you show for either Android or Linux,  (2) Using Terminal to type ```flutter run``` works perfectly for both Android and Linux,  finally, (3) F5 / Green Play Button works *Perfectly* fine for Chrome platform.  Why Chrome is unaffected by this behavior, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59727278/12206317). If your app runs fine in `flutter run --release` then that's what it actually matters.

Comment: it works fine in flutter run release. bit hot reload doesn't work.. it may the problem with my device but what i dont know till now.

Comment: I check the app on other devices it works but not on my vivo y20 device