# Is it possible to remove white screen when open the app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I created custom splash screen. and check with cache data and api data inside custom splash screen. if existing user available move to home page and if not move to login page.
But When the app open showing white black screen(native splash screen) and then showing my custom splash screen.

**Is it possible to remove it without editing native code(adding image or something, like** [Adding a splash screen to Flutter apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879103/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-apps))?

Comment: [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#updating-the-launch-screen) is the official way, whats wrong with it?

Comment: You can use the official way like @pskink's link refers and add your custom splash screen as well. If both UI remains exactly the same, user won't experience the difference and you can have your logic at that custom screen.

Comment: it's meaning before the app starting, running two pages. right? native splash screen and my splash screen?

Comment: [updating-the-launch-screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#updating-the-launch-screen) - this is the official way, did you try it?

Comment: yes, I tried...

Comment: I added color to a native splash screen and then load my custom splash screen and then load home or login page... but why load two splash screen?

Comment: I added cường-nguyễn way..it's working on android..is there way to do it like on ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android: You can add two lines to app/res/values/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to it on ios?

Comment: With ios: you can refer to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22188

Comment: I see comment: Confirming running flutter clean fixed things for me.

Comment: I haven't any issue.. I want to remove splash screen (native - black screen).. now, android way is working

Comment: You open Xcode to your project:
- Go to General
scroll down to App Icons and Launch Images
Change "Launch Screen File" to whatever your first view controller is, i.e. MainViewController
Your first view controller will now display instead of the Launch Image.