# How to create a splash screen in flutter with image and text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, splash-screen, flutter-dependencies

How Can I create a Splash Screen using an image which fits the screen and a text on that image ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a splash screen to Flutter apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879103/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-apps)