# Flutter AssetImage loads in slowly / with white screen

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I have noticed this issue a few times with times while loading my app in the emulator. My background image on my Homescreen seems to load in slow and shows a White screen/placeholder while it is loading.

Oddly enough, I've heard more complaints about this "white screen issue" from my iPhone users. They even complain about the screen just staying white and the image never loading.

I am just curious if this is something others have seen and if so, how you solved the issue.

```
        body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4), BlendMode.darken),
          image: const AssetImage(AppStrings.graffitLogo),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
     )
```

[image: Image of Homescreen after AssetImage is loaded]
[[image: AssetImage White screen issue]

Comment: If it is the first screen that load in your app, notice that there is few second takes to load your app thats the place for splash screen. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879103/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-apps

Comment: I have a SplashScreen before this page. (MainApp function, SplashScreen that waits 4 seconds, then this HomeScreen).

Comment: Hello, you can directly use "your_assets_folder/image" instead of Appstrings.graffitilogo, I dont know why you added that but that just makes your app do another process instead of fetching it directly, and remove const