# After i use native splash in my flutter project it still shows the default splash screen

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

currently i use flutter native splash in my project and still the default splash appear before the native splash i tried everything to sort it out but nothing works

removing the default splash screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1XbC.png)

Comment: you should post some of your code, please

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879103/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-apps?rq=2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used this package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash), and a lot people had this problem because they do not read its documentation well.
If you used this package, this may be the solution of your problem, run this command:

```
dart run flutter_native_splash:create
```