How do i add animated splash screen Natively in flutter?
I have gone through few articles and a youtube video but the way they are doing so is leading to a error as a error is thrown during build that cannot resolve SplashScreen
also one of the articles said that the method which i was trying was Deprecated all the articles i found are quite old and almost follow the same method can anyone tell me how can show animated splash screen in flutter

You can check this out. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879103/adding-a-splash-screen-to-flutter-apps?rq=2

Checkout this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

how do i use pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash for animated splash @Andreas

I added steps how to use the package.

How to use flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.1

On cmd inside you project directory run flutter pub add flutter_native_splash
Open pubspec.yaml file and above dev_dependencies paste the following:

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#33353f"
  image: assets\Futbol - New Logo Remove.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  #Commands to run in the terminal after you edit the splash screen in the pubspec.yaml file
  #1. flutter pub clean
  #2. flutter pub get
  #3. flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create

At the end execute the #1 #2 #3 commands on cmd under your project directory
*Replace image: to match the path of your image
